# Sorting columns in pandas dataframe based on column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with over 200 columns. The issue is as they were generated the order is

```
['Q1.3','Q6.1','Q1.2','Q1.1',......]
```

I need to *sort* the columns as follows:

```
['Q1.1','Q1.2','Q1.3',.....'Q6.1',......]
```

Is there some way for me to do this within Python?

Comment: The question has a banner at the top "This question already has answers here:
How to change the order of DataFrame columns? (34 answers)
Closed last year."
The question that it is saying is the same is a totally different question and this banner and link should therefore be removed.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, I believe it has been erroneously marked as duplicate: the supplied duplicate asks how to *reorder* columns whereas this question asks how to *sort* by column name. Strictly speaking answers to the latter are a subset of the former, but users seeking an answer to the latter are unlikely to find it in the answers to the duplicate (the highest-voted answer which mentions sorting is currently 5th in vote total).

Comment: I'm in complete agreement, the linked question is completely different. Why nobody will agree to reopen it is beyond me.

Answer (score 644, accepted):

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

This assumes that sorting the column names will give the order you want.  If your column names won't sort lexicographically (e.g., if you want column Q10.3 to appear after Q9.1), you'll need to sort differently, but that has nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: I like this because the same method can be used to sort rows (I needed to sort rows and columns). While it's the same method, you can omit the `axis`  argument (or provide its default value, `0`), like `df.reindex_axis(sorted(non_sorted_row_index))` which is equivalent to `df.reindex(sorted(non_sorted_row_index))`

Comment: Note that re-indexing is not done in-place, so to actually apply the sort to the df you have to use `df = df.reindex_axis(...)`. Also, note that non-lexicographical sorts are easy with this approach, since the list of column names can be sorted separately into an arbitrary order and then passed to `reindex_axis`. This is not possible with the alternative approach suggested by @Wes McKinney (`df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`), which is however cleaner for pure lexicographical sorts.

Comment: not sure when '.reindex_axis' was deprecated, see message below.

FutureWarning: '.reindex_axis' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use '.reindex' instead.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Comment: Does this actually sort the columns of dataframe? From first glance it seems like this would just sort the column names then reset the index.

Comment: `reindex_axis` is deprecated and results in `FutureWarning`. However, `.reindex` works fine. For the above example, use `df.reindex(columns=sorted(df.columns))`

Comment: [DataFrame.reindex documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

Comment: For the ones who need lexicographical sort, check naturalsort package in Python.

Comment: This is a good solution, but does not work if you have duplicate column names. The answer of @Wes McKinney works in that case. Hence, I think `df.sort_index(axis=1)` is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: for larger dfs, `reindex` is very slow

Comment: FYI this also works on a MultiIndex. Thanks.

Answer (score 485):

You can also do more succinctly:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

Make sure you assign the result back:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Or, do it in-place:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: remember to do `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`, per @multigoodverse

Comment: or modify `df` in-place with `df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: also, `sort_index` is faster than `reindex`, in case devs worry about it

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agree with @rsmith54 as this solution also works for duplicate column names.

Answer (score 76):

You can just do:

```
df[sorted(df.columns)]
```

---

Edit: Shorter is

```
df[sorted(df)]
```

Comment: I get "'DataFrame' object is not callable" for this. Version: pandas 0.14.

Comment: @lvelin, do you know why `sorted(df)` works, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @zyxue, `sorted` will be looking for the iterative class `magic methods` to figure out what to sort. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868228/is-there-a-magic-method-for-sorted-in-python

Answer (score 35):

For several columns, You can put columns order what you want:

```
#['A', 'B', 'C'] <-this is your columns order
df = df[['C', 'B', 'A']]
```

This example shows sorting and slicing columns:

```
d = {'col1':[1, 2, 3], 'col2':[4, 5, 6], 'col3':[7, 8, 9], 'col4':[17, 18, 19]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```

You get:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
 1     4     7    17
 2     5     8    18
 3     6     9    19
```

Then do:

```
df = df[['col3', 'col2', 'col1']]
```

Resulting in:

```
col3  col2  col1
7     4     1
8     5     2
9     6     3
```

Answer (score 28):

[Tweet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067079/841830) can be passed to BrenBarn's answer above with

```
data.reindex_axis(sorted(data.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])), axis=1)
```

So for your example, say:

```
vals = randint(low=16, high=80, size=25).reshape(5,5)
cols = ['Q1.3', 'Q6.1', 'Q1.2', 'Q9.1', 'Q10.2']
data = DataFrame(vals, columns = cols)
```

You get:

```
data

    Q1.3    Q6.1    Q1.2    Q9.1    Q10.2
0   73      29      63      51      72
1   61      29      32      68      57
2   36      49      76      18      37
3   63      61      51      30      31
4   36      66      71      24      77
```

Then do:

```
data.reindex_axis(sorted(data.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])), axis=1)
```

resulting in:

```
data


     Q1.2    Q1.3    Q6.1    Q9.1    Q10.2
0    2       0       1       3       4
1    7       5       6       8       9
2    2       0       1       3       4
3    2       0       1       3       4
4    2       0       1       3       4
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Replace reindex_axis with reindex for pandas >= 1.0

Answer (score 21):

If you need an arbitrary sequence instead of sorted sequence, you could do:

```
sequence = ['Q1.1','Q1.2','Q1.3',.....'Q6.1',......]
your_dataframe = your_dataframe.reindex(columns=sequence)
```

I tested this in 2.7.10 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Don't forget to add "inplace=True" to Wes' answer or set the result to a new DataFrame.

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

The quickest method is:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Be aware that this creates a new instance. Therefore you need to store the result in a new variable:

```
sortedDf=df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method and `sorted` function allow you to provide a custom function to extract the key used for comparison:

```
>>> ls = ['Q1.3', 'Q6.1', 'Q1.2']
>>> sorted(ls, key=lambda x: float(x[1:]))
['Q1.2', 'Q1.3', 'Q6.1']
```

Comment: This works for lists in general and I am familiar with it. How do I apply it to a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Not sure, I admit my answer was not specific to this library.

Answer (score 1):

One use-case is that you have named (some of) your columns with some prefix, and you want the columns sorted with those prefixes all together and in some particular order (not alphabetical).

For example, you might start all of your features with `Ft_`, labels with `Lbl_`, etc, and you want all unprefixed columns first, then all features, then the label. You can do this with the following function (I will note a possible efficiency problem using `sum` to reduce lists, but this isn't an issue unless you have a LOT of columns, which I do not):

```
def sortedcols(df, groups = ['Ft_', 'Lbl_'] ):
    return df[ sum([list(filter(re.compile(r).search, list(df.columns).copy())) for r in (lambda l: ['^(?!(%s))' % '|'.join(l)] + ['^%s' % i  for i in l ] )(groups)   ], [])  ]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
print df.sort_index(by='Frequency',ascending=False)
```

where by is the name of the column,if you want to sort the dataset based on column