# How to change the order of DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have the following DataFrame (`df`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))
```

I add more column(s) by assignment:

```py
df['mean'] = df.mean(1)
```

How can I move the column `mean` to the front, i.e. set it as first column leaving the order of the other columns untouched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Pandas - Re-ordering columns in a dataframe based on column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/python-pandas-re-ordering-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-name)

Comment: For a generalized NumPy-based solution see [How to move a column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616829/how-to-move-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe), assumes one column level only, i.e. no `MultiIndex`.

Comment: After searching enough, I got this best link for columns re-arranging multiple logics in pretty simple terms [columns re-arrange logic for pandas] [http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/re-arrange-or-re-order-the-column-of-dataframe-in-pandas-python-2]

Comment: In the end, the point is: `df = df[ list with newly arranged column names ]` ;D

Comment: For 2022, @WesMckinney's answer is more up to date than the top answer

Comment: For general ways to sort (or otherwise rearrange) the columns, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77616559/19123103).

Answer (score 1395):

One easy way would be to reassign the dataframe with a list of the columns, rearranged as needed.

This is what you have now:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
          0         1         2         3         4      mean
0  0.445598  0.173835  0.343415  0.682252  0.582616  0.445543
1  0.881592  0.696942  0.702232  0.696724  0.373551  0.670208
2  0.662527  0.955193  0.131016  0.609548  0.804694  0.632596
3  0.260919  0.783467  0.593433  0.033426  0.512019  0.436653
4  0.131842  0.799367  0.182828  0.683330  0.019485  0.363371
5  0.498784  0.873495  0.383811  0.699289  0.480447  0.587165
6  0.388771  0.395757  0.745237  0.628406  0.784473  0.588529
7  0.147986  0.459451  0.310961  0.706435  0.100914  0.345149
8  0.394947  0.863494  0.585030  0.565944  0.356561  0.553195
9  0.689260  0.865243  0.136481  0.386582  0.730399  0.561593

In [7]: cols = df.columns.tolist()

In [8]: cols
Out[8]: [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 'mean']
```

Rearrange `cols` in any way you want. This is how I moved the last element to the first position:

```
In [12]: cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]

In [13]: cols
Out[13]: ['mean', 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L]
```

Then reorder the dataframe like this:

```
In [16]: df = df[cols]  #    OR    df = df.ix[:, cols]

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
       mean         0         1         2         3         4
0  0.445543  0.445598  0.173835  0.343415  0.682252  0.582616
1  0.670208  0.881592  0.696942  0.702232  0.696724  0.373551
2  0.632596  0.662527  0.955193  0.131016  0.609548  0.804694
3  0.436653  0.260919  0.783467  0.593433  0.033426  0.512019
4  0.363371  0.131842  0.799367  0.182828  0.683330  0.019485
5  0.587165  0.498784  0.873495  0.383811  0.699289  0.480447
6  0.588529  0.388771  0.395757  0.745237  0.628406  0.784473
7  0.345149  0.147986  0.459451  0.310961  0.706435  0.100914
8  0.553195  0.394947  0.863494  0.585030  0.565944  0.356561
9  0.561593  0.689260  0.865243  0.136481  0.386582  0.730399
```

Comment: incase you get "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" make sure you [] the str value in cols:
cols = [cols[7]] + cols[:7] + cols[8:]

Comment: Is there any reason to use `df.ix[:, cols]` over `df[cols]`?

Comment: `FutureWarning: using '+' to provide set union with Indexes is deprecated, use '|' or .union()
  '''`. I suggest replacing the `cols` line with `cols[-1:].union(cols[:-1])`, which yields the same result.

Comment: @FooBar That's not a set union it's a concatenation of two ordered lists.

Comment: @Aman I'm just pointing out that your code is deprecated. Your handling of your post is at your discretion.

Comment: @FooBar, the type of `cols` is `list`; it even allows duplicates (which will be discarded when used on the dataframe). You are thinking of `Index` objects.

Comment: This implies copying ALL the data, which is highly inefficient. I wished pandas had a way to do that without creating a copy.

Answer (score 866):

You could also do something like this:

```
df = df[['mean', '0', '1', '2', '3']]
```

You can get the list of columns with:

```
cols = list(df.columns.values)
```

The output will produce:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', 'mean']
```

...which is then easy to rearrange manually before dropping it into the first function

Comment: You could also get the list of columns with list(df.columns)

Comment: or `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: For newbies like me, re-arrange the list you get from cols. Then df=df[cols] i.e. the re-arranged list gets dropped into the first expression without only one set of brackets.

Comment: Column names will be integers in 3.x `df = df[['mean1', 0, 1, 2, 3]]` ✓

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer as it does not provide code how to change column order of any dataframe. Say i import a csv file as pandas pd as ```pd.read_csv()``` . How can your answer be used to change the column order?

Comment: @Robvh, the second line of code explains how to get the existing column names.  From there, you can copy the output into the first line of code, and re-arrange as desired.  The only other piece of information to know is that without a header, the default column names are integers, not strings.

Comment: I would agree. This is a simple, straightforward solution to the problem. Though if you are dealing with large numbers of columns it's not ideal. Helped me out tho

Answer (score 417):

Just assign the column names in the order you want them:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
          0         1         2         3         4  mean
0  0.172742  0.915661  0.043387  0.712833  0.190717     1
1  0.128186  0.424771  0.590779  0.771080  0.617472     1
2  0.125709  0.085894  0.989798  0.829491  0.155563     1
3  0.742578  0.104061  0.299708  0.616751  0.951802     1
4  0.721118  0.528156  0.421360  0.105886  0.322311     1
5  0.900878  0.082047  0.224656  0.195162  0.736652     1
6  0.897832  0.558108  0.318016  0.586563  0.507564     1
7  0.027178  0.375183  0.930248  0.921786  0.337060     1
8  0.763028  0.182905  0.931756  0.110675  0.423398     1
9  0.848996  0.310562  0.140873  0.304561  0.417808     1

In [40]: df = df[['mean', 4,3,2,1]]
```

Now, 'mean' column comes out in the front:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
   mean         4         3         2         1
0     1  0.190717  0.712833  0.043387  0.915661
1     1  0.617472  0.771080  0.590779  0.424771
2     1  0.155563  0.829491  0.989798  0.085894
3     1  0.951802  0.616751  0.299708  0.104061
4     1  0.322311  0.105886  0.421360  0.528156
5     1  0.736652  0.195162  0.224656  0.082047
6     1  0.507564  0.586563  0.318016  0.558108
7     1  0.337060  0.921786  0.930248  0.375183
8     1  0.423398  0.110675  0.931756  0.182905
9     1  0.417808  0.304561  0.140873  0.310562
```

Comment: Does it make a copy?

Comment: @NicholasMorley - This isn't the best answer if you have, say, 1000 columns in your df.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you're assigning to `<df>.columns` like you claim initially

Comment: This is the best answer for a small number of columns.

Comment: This is just a copy of @freddygv 's earlier answer. That one should be the accepted answer, not this.

Answer (score 379):

For pandas >= 1.3 (Edited in 2022):

```
df.insert(0, 'mean', df.pop('mean'))
```

How about   (for Pandas < 1.3, the original answer)

```
df.insert(0, 'mean', df['mean'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion

Comment: Could this be a future feature add to `pandas`? something like `df.move(0,df.mean)`?

Comment: Oh man, it even works like this `df_metadata.insert(0,'Db_name',"raw_data")` (Code not relevant to this thread)

Comment: This is a scalable solution since other solutions are manually typing column names.

Comment: This works for the OP's question, when creating a new column, but it doesn't for moving a column; attempt to move results in `*** ValueError: cannot insert mean, already exists`

Comment: This is a clean solution. The modern API method is:  [`df.insert(0, 'mean', df['mean'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html?highlight=pandas%20insert#pandas.DataFrame.insert)

Comment: New documentation link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion

Comment: @spinup if you already have the column, you can insert under different temporary name, drop the original column and then return temp name to the original: `df.insert(0, 'mean_temp', df['mean']) df.drop('mean', axis=1, inplace=True) df.rename(columns={'mean_temp': 'mean'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: With newest pandas versions it throws an error if the column exists already. However, there is very simple solution:

df.insert(0, "mean", df.pop("mean"))

Just "pop" the same column.

Comment: This is sensational.

Comment: Works well, but I do get a warning "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.". To move a column to the end, standard python index "-1" doesn't work, so use len(df.columns)-1, as in `df.insert(len(df.columns)-1, 'mean', df.pop('mean'))`

Answer (score 206):

In your case,

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['mean',0,1,2,3,4])
```

will do exactly what you want.

**In my case (general form):**

```
df = df.reindex(columns=sorted(df.columns))
df = df.reindex(columns=(['opened'] + list([a for a in df.columns if a != 'opened']) ))
```

Comment: I tried to set `copy=False` but it looks like `reindex_axis` still creates a copy.

Comment: @Konstantin can you create another question about this issue? It would be better to have more context

Comment: @Konstantin  just curious, did you debug to see that `copy=False` creates a copy? the documentation claimed that when `copy=True`, `reindex` returns a new object, suggesting that it'd be the same old object otherwise; if it is the same object, how could be it a copy?

Answer (score 125):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
column_names = ['x','y','z','mean']
for col in column_names: 
    df[col] = np.random.randint(0,100, size=10000)
```

You can try out the following solutions :

**Solution 1:**

```
df = df[ ['mean'] + [ col for col in df.columns if col != 'mean' ] ]
```

**Solution 2:**

---

```
df = df[['mean', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
```

---

**Solution 3:**

```
col = df.pop("mean")
df = df.insert(0, col.name, col)
```

---

**Solution 4:**

```
df.set_index(df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

**Solution 5:**

```
cols = list(df)
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]
```

---

**solution 6:**

```
order = [1,2,3,0] # setting column's order
df = df[[df.columns[i] for i in order]]
```

### Time Comparison:

**Solution 1:**

> CPU times: user 1.05 ms, sys: 35 µs, total: 1.08 ms Wall time: 995 µs

**Solution 2**:

> CPU times: user 933 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 933 µs
>   Wall time: 800 µs

**Solution 3**:

> CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 1.35 ms, total: 1.35 ms
>   Wall time: 1.08 ms

**Solution 4**:

> CPU times: user 1.23 ms, sys: 45 µs, total: 1.27 ms
>   Wall time: 986 µs

**Solution 5**:

> CPU times: user 1.09 ms, sys: 19 µs, total: 1.11 ms
>   Wall time: 949 µs

**Solution 6**:

> CPU times: user 955 µs, sys: 34 µs, total: 989 µs
>   Wall time: 859 µs

Comment: solution 1 is what I needed as I have too many columns(53), thanks

Comment: @Pygirl wich value shows real comsumed time? (user, sys, total or wall time)

Comment: This is for me the best answer for the problem. So many solutions(including one that I needed) and simple approach. Thanks!

Comment: **Solution 6** (no list comprehension): `df = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 0]]`

Comment: @sergzemsk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55702033/6660373. I compare by wall time.

Comment: Solution 3 is the only good approach from among the ones listed because it's the only one that's in-place and doesn't mess with the index. Those that are not in place are not scalable.

Answer (score 83):

You need to create a new list of your columns in the desired order, then use `df = df[cols]` to rearrange the columns in this new order.

```
cols = ['mean']  + [col for col in df if col != 'mean']
df = df[cols]
```

You can also use a more general approach.  In this example, the last column (indicated by -1) is inserted as the first column.

```
cols = [df.columns[-1]] + [col for col in df if col != df.columns[-1]]
df = df[cols]
```

You can also use this approach for reordering columns in a desired order if they are present in the DataFrame.

```
inserted_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cols = ([col for col in inserted_cols if col in df] 
        + [col for col in df if col not in inserted_cols])
df = df[cols]
```

Answer (score 73):

Suppose you have `df` with columns `A` `B` `C`.

The most simple way is:

```
df = df.reindex(['B','C','A'], axis=1)
```

Comment: One great thing about this option is that you can use it in pandas pipe operations!

Comment: Note that this will only return a reindexed data frame - not change the `df` instance which is being used. If you want to use the reindexed df, simply use the returned value: `df2 = df.reindex(['B', 'C', 'A'], axis=1)`. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @cheevahagadog Good Point!

Comment: @AndreasForslöw Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 68):

This question has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/python-pandas-re-ordering-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-name) but `reindex_axis` is deprecated now so I would suggest to use:

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

For those who want to specify the order they want instead of just sorting them, here's the solution spelled out:

```
df = df.reindex(['the','order','you','want'], axis=1)
```

Now, how you want to sort the list of column names is really not a `pandas` question, that's a Python list manipulation question. There are many ways of doing that, and I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935892/1479269) has a very neat way of doing it.

Comment: No, that's different. There the user wants to sort all columns by name. Here they want to move one column to the first column while leaving the order of the other columns untouched.

Comment: What if you don't want them sorted?

Comment: The answer doesn't deal with the problem in the question.

Comment: @mins I hope the edit above is clear enough. :)

Comment: Your edit now shows a working solution to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Solved my problem: df = df.reindex(['the','order','you','want'], axis=1)

Comment: Best answer, clean and to the point...

Answer (score 66):

If your column names are too-long-to-type then you could specify the new order through a list of integers with the positions:

Data:

```
          0         1         2         3         4      mean
0  0.397312  0.361846  0.719802  0.575223  0.449205  0.500678
1  0.287256  0.522337  0.992154  0.584221  0.042739  0.485741
2  0.884812  0.464172  0.149296  0.167698  0.793634  0.491923
3  0.656891  0.500179  0.046006  0.862769  0.651065  0.543382
4  0.673702  0.223489  0.438760  0.468954  0.308509  0.422683
5  0.764020  0.093050  0.100932  0.572475  0.416471  0.389390
6  0.259181  0.248186  0.626101  0.556980  0.559413  0.449972
7  0.400591  0.075461  0.096072  0.308755  0.157078  0.207592
8  0.639745  0.368987  0.340573  0.997547  0.011892  0.471749
9  0.050582  0.714160  0.168839  0.899230  0.359690  0.438500
```

Generic example:

```
new_order = [3,2,1,4,5,0]
print(df[df.columns[new_order]])  

          3         2         1         4      mean         0
0  0.575223  0.719802  0.361846  0.449205  0.500678  0.397312
1  0.584221  0.992154  0.522337  0.042739  0.485741  0.287256
2  0.167698  0.149296  0.464172  0.793634  0.491923  0.884812
3  0.862769  0.046006  0.500179  0.651065  0.543382  0.656891
4  0.468954  0.438760  0.223489  0.308509  0.422683  0.673702
5  0.572475  0.100932  0.093050  0.416471  0.389390  0.764020
6  0.556980  0.626101  0.248186  0.559413  0.449972  0.259181
7  0.308755  0.096072  0.075461  0.157078  0.207592  0.400591
8  0.997547  0.340573  0.368987  0.011892  0.471749  0.639745
9  0.899230  0.168839  0.714160  0.359690  0.438500  0.050582
```

Although it might seem like I'm just explicitly typing the column names in a different order, the fact that there's a column 'mean' should make it clear that `new_order` relates to actual positions and not column names.

For the specific case of OP's question:

```
new_order = [-1,0,1,2,3,4]
df = df[df.columns[new_order]]
print(df)

       mean         0         1         2         3         4
0  0.500678  0.397312  0.361846  0.719802  0.575223  0.449205
1  0.485741  0.287256  0.522337  0.992154  0.584221  0.042739
2  0.491923  0.884812  0.464172  0.149296  0.167698  0.793634
3  0.543382  0.656891  0.500179  0.046006  0.862769  0.651065
4  0.422683  0.673702  0.223489  0.438760  0.468954  0.308509
5  0.389390  0.764020  0.093050  0.100932  0.572475  0.416471
6  0.449972  0.259181  0.248186  0.626101  0.556980  0.559413
7  0.207592  0.400591  0.075461  0.096072  0.308755  0.157078
8  0.471749  0.639745  0.368987  0.340573  0.997547  0.011892
9  0.438500  0.050582  0.714160  0.168839  0.899230  0.359690
```

The main problem with this approach is that calling the same code multiple times will create different results each time, so one needs to be careful :)

Answer (score 37):

You can reorder the dataframe columns using a list of names with:

```
df = df.filter(['list', 'of', 'column', 'names'])
```

[pandas .filter docs](https://devdocs.io/pandas%7E1/reference/api/pandas.dataframe.filter)

Answer (score 29):

I think this is a slightly neater solution:

```py
df.insert(0, 'mean', df.pop("mean"))
```

This solution is somewhat similar to @JoeHeffer 's solution but this is one liner.

Here we remove the column `"mean"` from the dataframe and attach it to index `0` with the same column name.

Comment: this is nice, but what if you want it to go at the end?

Comment: Any new column you create is added to the end, so I guess it would be `df["mean"] = df.pop("mean")`

Answer (score 23):

I ran into a similar question myself, and just wanted to add what I settled on. I liked the `reindex_axis() method` for changing column order. This worked:

```
df = df.reindex_axis(['mean'] + list(df.columns[:-1]), axis=1)
```

An alternate method based on the comment from @Jorge:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['mean'] + list(df.columns[:-1]))
```

Although `reindex_axis` seems to be slightly faster in micro benchmarks than `reindex`, I think I prefer the latter for its directness.

Comment: This was a nice solution, but reindex_axis will be deprecated. I used reindex, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I may miss something but 1/ you likely forgot to include `axis=1` in this second solution to use the columns, not the rows. 2/ In 2020, the `reindex` solution changes the rows/columns order, but also clears data (`NaN` everywhere).

Answer (score 21):

Here's a way to move one existing column that will modify the existing dataframe in place.

```
my_column = df.pop('column name')
df.insert(3, my_column.name, my_column)  # Is in-place
```

Comment: This is pretty much the only good approach as it's in-place. Most other approaches are not in-place and are therefore not scalable.

Answer (score 20):

This function avoids you having to list out every variable in your dataset just to order a few of them.

```
def order(frame,var):
    if type(var) is str:
        var = [var] #let the command take a string or list
    varlist =[w for w in frame.columns if w not in var]
    frame = frame[var+varlist]
    return frame
```

It takes two arguments, the first is the dataset, the second are the columns in the data set that you want to bring to the front.

So in my case I have a data set called Frame with variables A1, A2, B1, B2, Total and Date. If I want to bring Total to the front then all I have to do is:

```
frame = order(frame,['Total'])
```

If I want to bring Total and Date to the front then I do:

```
frame = order(frame,['Total','Date'])
```

EDIT:

Another useful way to use this is, if you have an unfamiliar table and you're looking with variables with a particular term in them, like VAR1, VAR2,... you may execute something like:

```
frame = order(frame,[v for v in frame.columns if "VAR" in v])
```

Answer (score 19):

Simply do,

```
df = df[['mean'] + df.columns[:-1].tolist()]
```

Comment: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: could be API has changed, you can also do this...

`order = df.columns.tolist()`
`df['mean'] = df.mean(1)`
`df.columns = ['mean'] + order`

Comment: A variation of this worked well for me. With an existing list, `headers`, that was used to create a dict that was then used to create the DataFrame, I called `df.reindex(columns=headers)`. The only problem I ran into was I had already called `df.set_index('some header name', inplace=True)`, so when the reindex was done, it added another column named `some header name` since the original column was now the index.

As for the syntax specified above, `['mean'] + df.columns` in the python interpreter gives me `Index(u'meanAddress', u'meanCity', u'meanFirst Name'...`

Comment: @hlongmore: I don't know your prior code is, but the edit should work (using 0.19.2)

Comment: The edit does indeed work (I'm on 0.20.2). In my case, I've already got the columns I want, so I think df.reindex() is what I really should use.

Comment: This answer appears to be wrong: it does not move the mean column so that it is the first column. Rather, it renames the first column to "mean" and renames the last column to 4. I was almost misled to doing something very wrong, but luckily checked it myself first. I would suggest doing something like: "df = df[list(reversed(df.columns))]" instead, or see some of the other answers for variations on this.

Comment: Oops how could I miss that? Prior to my edit before, it's still works though. I've re-edited my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Just type the column name you want to change, and set the index for the new location.

```
def change_column_order(df, col_name, index):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols.remove(col_name)
    cols.insert(index, col_name)
    return df[cols]
```

For your case, this would be like:

```
df = change_column_order(df, 'mean', 0)
```

Answer (score 12):

You could do the following (borrowing parts from Aman's answer):

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(-1))

cols
>>>['mean', 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L]

df = df[cols]
```

Answer (score 11):

Moving any column to any position:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 
                   "B": [2,4,8], 
                   "C": [5,5,5]})

cols = df.columns.tolist()
column_to_move = "C"
new_position = 1

cols.insert(new_position, cols.pop(cols.index(column_to_move)))
df = df[cols]
```

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to bring two columns in front from a dataframe where I do not know exactly the names of all columns, because they are generated from a pivot statement before.
So, if you are in the same situation: To bring columns in front that you know the name of and then let them follow by "all the other columns", I came up with the following general solution:

```
df = df.reindex_axis(['Col1','Col2'] + list(df.columns.drop(['Col1','Col2'])), axis=1)
```

Comment: FutureWarning: '.reindex_axis' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use '.reindex' instead.

Answer (score 6):

#### Here is a very simple answer to this(only one line).

You can do that after you added the 'n' column into your df as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))
df['mean'] = df.mean(1)
df
           0           1           2           3           4        mean
0   0.929616    0.316376    0.183919    0.204560    0.567725    0.440439
1   0.595545    0.964515    0.653177    0.748907    0.653570    0.723143
2   0.747715    0.961307    0.008388    0.106444    0.298704    0.424512
3   0.656411    0.809813    0.872176    0.964648    0.723685    0.805347
4   0.642475    0.717454    0.467599    0.325585    0.439645    0.518551
5   0.729689    0.994015    0.676874    0.790823    0.170914    0.672463
6   0.026849    0.800370    0.903723    0.024676    0.491747    0.449473
7   0.526255    0.596366    0.051958    0.895090    0.728266    0.559587
8   0.818350    0.500223    0.810189    0.095969    0.218950    0.488736
9   0.258719    0.468106    0.459373    0.709510    0.178053    0.414752


### here you can add below line and it should work 
# Don't forget the two (()) 'brackets' around columns names.Otherwise, it'll give you an error.

df = df[list(('mean',0, 1, 2,3,4))]
df

        mean           0           1           2           3           4
0   0.440439    0.929616    0.316376    0.183919    0.204560    0.567725
1   0.723143    0.595545    0.964515    0.653177    0.748907    0.653570
2   0.424512    0.747715    0.961307    0.008388    0.106444    0.298704
3   0.805347    0.656411    0.809813    0.872176    0.964648    0.723685
4   0.518551    0.642475    0.717454    0.467599    0.325585    0.439645
5   0.672463    0.729689    0.994015    0.676874    0.790823    0.170914
6   0.449473    0.026849    0.800370    0.903723    0.024676    0.491747
7   0.559587    0.526255    0.596366    0.051958    0.895090    0.728266
8   0.488736    0.818350    0.500223    0.810189    0.095969    0.218950
9   0.414752    0.258719    0.468106    0.459373    0.709510    0.178053
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a set which is an *unordered collection of unique elements* to do keep the "order of the other columns untouched":

```
other_columns = list(set(df.columns).difference(["mean"])) #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, you can use a lambda to move a specific column to the front by:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                               

In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                                              

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))                                                         

In [4]: df["mean"] = df.mean(1)                                                                          

In [5]: move_col_to_front = lambda df, col: df[[col]+list(set(df.columns).difference([col]))]            

In [6]: move_col_to_front(df, "mean")                                                                    
Out[6]: 
       mean         0         1         2         3         4
0  0.697253  0.600377  0.464852  0.938360  0.945293  0.537384
1  0.609213  0.703387  0.096176  0.971407  0.955666  0.319429
2  0.561261  0.791842  0.302573  0.662365  0.728368  0.321158
3  0.518720  0.710443  0.504060  0.663423  0.208756  0.506916
4  0.616316  0.665932  0.794385  0.163000  0.664265  0.793995
5  0.519757  0.585462  0.653995  0.338893  0.714782  0.305654
6  0.532584  0.434472  0.283501  0.633156  0.317520  0.994271
7  0.640571  0.732680  0.187151  0.937983  0.921097  0.423945
8  0.562447  0.790987  0.200080  0.317812  0.641340  0.862018
9  0.563092  0.811533  0.662709  0.396048  0.596528  0.348642

In [7]: move_col_to_front(df, 2)                                                                         
Out[7]: 
          2         0         1         3         4      mean
0  0.938360  0.600377  0.464852  0.945293  0.537384  0.697253
1  0.971407  0.703387  0.096176  0.955666  0.319429  0.609213
2  0.662365  0.791842  0.302573  0.728368  0.321158  0.561261
3  0.663423  0.710443  0.504060  0.208756  0.506916  0.518720
4  0.163000  0.665932  0.794385  0.664265  0.793995  0.616316
5  0.338893  0.585462  0.653995  0.714782  0.305654  0.519757
6  0.633156  0.434472  0.283501  0.317520  0.994271  0.532584
7  0.937983  0.732680  0.187151  0.921097  0.423945  0.640571
8  0.317812  0.790987  0.200080  0.641340  0.862018  0.562447
9  0.396048  0.811533  0.662709  0.596528  0.348642  0.563092
```

Answer (score 5):

Just flipping helps often.

```
df[df.columns[::-1]]
```

Or just shuffle for a look.

```
import random
cols = list(df.columns)
random.shuffle(cols)
df[cols]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reindex` which can be used for both axis:

```
df
#           0         1         2         3         4      mean
# 0  0.943825  0.202490  0.071908  0.452985  0.678397  0.469921
# 1  0.745569  0.103029  0.268984  0.663710  0.037813  0.363821
# 2  0.693016  0.621525  0.031589  0.956703  0.118434  0.484254
# 3  0.284922  0.527293  0.791596  0.243768  0.629102  0.495336
# 4  0.354870  0.113014  0.326395  0.656415  0.172445  0.324628
# 5  0.815584  0.532382  0.195437  0.829670  0.019001  0.478415
# 6  0.944587  0.068690  0.811771  0.006846  0.698785  0.506136
# 7  0.595077  0.437571  0.023520  0.772187  0.862554  0.538182
# 8  0.700771  0.413958  0.097996  0.355228  0.656919  0.444974
# 9  0.263138  0.906283  0.121386  0.624336  0.859904  0.555009

df.reindex(['mean', *range(5)], axis=1)

#        mean         0         1         2         3         4
# 0  0.469921  0.943825  0.202490  0.071908  0.452985  0.678397
# 1  0.363821  0.745569  0.103029  0.268984  0.663710  0.037813
# 2  0.484254  0.693016  0.621525  0.031589  0.956703  0.118434
# 3  0.495336  0.284922  0.527293  0.791596  0.243768  0.629102
# 4  0.324628  0.354870  0.113014  0.326395  0.656415  0.172445
# 5  0.478415  0.815584  0.532382  0.195437  0.829670  0.019001
# 6  0.506136  0.944587  0.068690  0.811771  0.006846  0.698785
# 7  0.538182  0.595077  0.437571  0.023520  0.772187  0.862554
# 8  0.444974  0.700771  0.413958  0.097996  0.355228  0.656919
# 9  0.555009  0.263138  0.906283  0.121386  0.624336  0.859904
```

Answer (score 4):

Hackiest method in the book

```
df.insert(0, "test", df["mean"])
df = df.drop(columns=["mean"]).rename(columns={"test": "mean"})
```

Answer (score 4):

A pretty straightforward solution that worked for me is to use `.reindex` on `df.columns`:

```
df = df[df.columns.reindex(['mean', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])[0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is using **`set()`**, in particular when you have a long list of columns and do not want to handle them manually:

```
cols = list(set(df.columns.tolist()) - set(['mean']))
cols.insert(0, 'mean')
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: One caution: the order of columns goes away if you put it into set

Comment: Interesting! @user1930402 I have tried the approach above on several occasions and never had any problem. I will double check again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function to do this for any number of columns.

```
def mean_first(df):
    ncols = df.shape[1]        # Get the number of columns
    index = list(range(ncols)) # Create an index to reorder the columns
    index.insert(0,ncols)      # This puts the last column at the front
    return(df.assign(mean=df.mean(1)).iloc[:,index]) # new df with last column (mean) first
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a super easy way to do it. If you're copying the headers from excel use `.split('\t')`

```
df = df['FILE_NAME DISPLAY_PATH SHAREPOINT_PATH RETAILER LAST_UPDATE'.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe [@Aman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148611/1082349) is the best if you know the location of the other column.

If you don't know the location of `mean`, but only have its name, you  cannot resort directly to `cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]`. Following is the next-best thing I could come up with:

```
meanDf = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('mean'))
# now df doesn't contain "mean" anymore. Order of join will move it to left or right:
meanDf.join(df) # has mean as first column
df.join(meanDf) # has mean as last column
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `T`?

```
df = df.T.reindex(['mean', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).T
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked [Shoresh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166838/9075180) to use set functionality to remove columns when you don't know the location, however this didn't work for my purpose as I need to keep the original column order (which has arbitrary column labels).

I got this to work though by using [IndexedSet](http://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setutils.html#) from the boltons package.

I also needed to re-add multiple column labels, so for a more general case I used the following code:

```
from boltons.setutils import IndexedSet
cols = list(IndexedSet(df.columns.tolist()) - set(['mean', 'std']))
cols[0:0] =['mean', 'std']
df = df[cols]
```

Hope this is useful to anyone searching this thread for a general solution.

Comment: I am a bit surprised! I use `set` for this purpose quite often and never had to deal with ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers did not generalize enough and pandas reindex_axis method is a little tedious, hence I offer a simple function to move an arbitrary number of columns to any position using a dictionary where key = column name and value = position to move to. If your dataframe is large pass True to 'big_data' then the function will return the ordered columns list. And you could use this list to slice your data.

```
def order_column(df, columns, big_data = False):

    """Re-Orders dataFrame column(s)
       Parameters : 
       df      -- dataframe
       columns -- a dictionary:
                  key   = current column position/index or column name
                  value = position to move it to  
       big_data -- boolean 
                  True = returns only the ordered columns as a list
                          the user user can then slice the data using this
                          ordered column
                  False = default - return a copy of the dataframe
    """
    ordered_col = df.columns.tolist()

    for key, value in columns.items():

        ordered_col.remove(key)
        ordered_col.insert(value, key)

    if big_data:

        return ordered_col

    return df[ordered_col]

# e.g.
df = pd.DataFrame({'chicken wings': np.random.rand(10, 1).flatten(), 'taco': np.random.rand(10,1).flatten(),
                          'coffee': np.random.rand(10, 1).flatten()})
df['mean'] = df.mean(1)

df = order_column(df, {'mean': 0, 'coffee':1 })

>>>
```

[image: output]

```
col = order_column(df, {'mean': 0, 'coffee':1 }, True)

col
>>>
['mean', 'coffee', 'chicken wings', 'taco']

# you could grab it by doing this

df = df[col]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a very specific use case for re-ordering column names in pandas.  Sometimes I am creating a new column in a dataframe that is based on an existing column.  By default pandas will insert my new column at the end, but I want the new column to be inserted next to the existing column it's derived from.

[image]

```py
def rearrange_list(input_list, input_item_to_move, input_item_insert_here):
    '''
    Helper function to re-arrange the order of items in a list.
    Useful for moving column in pandas dataframe.

    Inputs:
        input_list - list
        input_item_to_move - item in list to move
        input_item_insert_here - item in list, insert before 

    returns:
        output_list
    '''
    # make copy for output, make sure it's a list
    output_list = list(input_list)

    # index of item to move
    idx_move = output_list.index(input_item_to_move)

    # pop off the item to move
    itm_move = output_list.pop(idx_move)

    # index of item to insert here
    idx_insert = output_list.index(input_item_insert_here)

    # insert item to move into here
    output_list.insert(idx_insert, itm_move)

    return output_list


import pandas as pd

# step 1: create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'motorcycle': ['motorcycle1', 'motorcycle2', 'motorcycle3'],
    'initial_odometer': [101, 500, 322],
    'final_odometer': [201, 515, 463],
    'other_col_1': ['blah', 'blah', 'blah'],
    'other_col_2': ['blah', 'blah', 'blah']
})
print('Step 1: create sample dataframe')
display(df)
print()

# step 2: add new column that is difference between final and initial
df['change_odometer'] = df['final_odometer']-df['initial_odometer']
print('Step 2: add new column')
display(df)
print()

# step 3: rearrange columns
ls_cols = df.columns
ls_cols = rearrange_list(ls_cols, 'change_odometer', 'final_odometer')
df=df[ls_cols]
print('Step 3: rearrange columns')
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this function is more straightforward. You Just need to specify a subset of columns at the start or the end or both:

```
def reorder_df_columns(df, start=None, end=None):
    """
        This function reorder columns of a DataFrame.
        It takes columns given in the list `start` and move them to the left.
        Its also takes columns in `end` and move them to the right.
    """
    if start is None:
        start = []
    if end is None:
        end = []
    assert isinstance(start, list) and isinstance(end, list)
    cols = list(df.columns)
    for c in start:
        if c not in cols:
            start.remove(c)
    for c in end:
        if c not in cols or c in start:
            end.remove(c)
    for c in start + end:
        cols.remove(c)
    cols = start + cols + end
    return df[cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the top answer, there is an alternative using deque() and its rotate() method. The rotate method takes the last element in the list and inserts it to the beginning:

```
from collections import deque

columns = deque(df.columns.tolist())
columns.rotate()

df = df[columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.sort_index(axis=1)` is quite clean.[Check doc here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).
And then `concat`

Comment: Though the function `sort_index` is clean, I am sorry to say, but I don't think that it  addresses the question, which is more about rearranging the columns (which may or may not follow any particular order) than sorting them.

Answer (score 0):

To set an existing column right/left of another, based on their names:

```
def df_move_column(df, col_to_move, col_left_of_destiny="", right_of_col_bool=True):
    cols = list(df.columns.values)
    index_max = len(cols) - 1

    if not right_of_col_bool:
        # set left of a column "c", is like putting right of column previous to "c"
        # ... except if left of 1st column, then recursive call to set rest right to it
        aux = cols.index(col_left_of_destiny)
        if not aux:
            for g in [x for x in cols[::-1] if x != col_to_move]:
                df = df_move_column(
                        df, 
                        col_to_move=g, 
                        col_left_of_destiny=col_to_move
                        )
            return df
        col_left_of_destiny = cols[aux - 1]

    index_old = cols.index(col_to_move)
    index_new = 0
    if len(col_left_of_destiny):
        index_new = cols.index(col_left_of_destiny) + 1

    if index_old == index_new:
        return df

    if index_new < index_old:
        index_new = np.min([index_new, index_max])
        cols = (
            cols[:index_new]
            + [cols[index_old]]
            + cols[index_new:index_old]
            + cols[index_old + 1 :]
        )
    else:
        cols = (
            cols[:index_old]
            + cols[index_old + 1 : index_new]
            + [cols[index_old]]
            + cols[index_new:]
        )

    df = df[cols]
    return df
```

E.g.

```
cols = list("ABCD")
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4)[np.newaxis, :], columns=cols)
for k in cols:
    print(30 * "-")
    for g in [x for x in cols if x != k]:
        df_new = df_move_column(df2, k, g)
        print(f"{k} after {g}:  {df_new.columns.values}")
for k in cols:
    print(30 * "-")
    for g in [x for x in cols if x != k]:
        df_new = df_move_column(df2, k, g, right_of_col_bool=False)
        print(f"{k} before {g}:  {df_new.columns.values}")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought of the same as Dmitriy Work, clearly easiest answer:

```
df["mean"] = df.mean(1)
l =  list(np.arange(0,len(df.columns) -1 ))
l.insert(0,-1)
df.iloc[:,l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method followed by a [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Note that we first `pop()` the column we intend to move to the front of the dataframe, so that we avoid name collision when resetting the index:

```
df.set_index(df.pop('column_name'), inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

For more details see [How to change the order of dataframe columns in pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns-in-pandas-c91370326053).

Answer (score 0):

### Sort columns (inside pandas) using [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

You can also use `sort_index()` with a sorting key. Just like you can rearrange a list in any order you want by passing a sorting key to the built-in `sorted()` function, you can also rearrange pandas columns using a sorting key. However, unlike the key in `sorted()`, this key must be a vectorized function, which means it must return the whole list of positions at once.

For the current example where we want to move `'mean'` to front the shift all other columns to the right, we can do the following.

- Create a dictionary where each column label has a corresponding integer value. We want `'mean'` column to have the lowest integer value so that it can be treated to have the lowest key.
- Define `sorting_key` function that maps the dictionary defined above to the columns.
- Pass `sorting_key` function as the `sort_index()` key.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 5))
df['mean'] = df.mean(1)
mapping = {col: pos for pos, col in enumerate(df.columns)} | {'mean': -1}
sorting_key = lambda cols: cols.map(mapping)
df.sort_index(axis=1, key=sorting_key)
```

This outputs the following:

[image: result]

---

### Sort columns outside of pandas and select columns

That said, we can always rearrange the columns outside of pandas and simply use `__getitem__` a.k.a `[]`, `reindex()` or `get()` to reorder the columns accordingly. Once you reorder the column labels (outside of pandas) such as

```py
cols = ['mean', *df.columns.drop('mean')]

# or
cols = ['mean'] + df.columns[:-1].tolist()

# or
mapping = {col: pos for pos, col in enumerate(df.columns)} | {'mean': -1}
cols = sorted(df.columns, key=mapping.get)
```

then it becomes a problem of selecting columns according to it (which is a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285613/19123103)).

Here are some column selection methods (most of which already exist in other answers on this page) that preserve the list order:

- label-based:

  ```py
  cols = ['mean', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  df = df[cols]                          # []
  df = df.loc[:, cols]                   # .loc[]
  df = df.reindex(columns=cols)          # reindex()
  df = df.get(cols)                      # get()
  ```
- index-based

  ```py
  idx = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  df = df.take(idx, axis=1)              # take()
  df = df.iloc[:, idx]                   # iloc[]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.reindex(columns=["second", "first"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I tried making a order function which you can reorder/move column(s) with reference of order command of Stata. it would be better to make a py file( the name of which may be order.py) and save it in a directory and call it function

```
def order(dataframe,cols,f_or_l=None,before=None, after=None):

#만든이: 김완석, Stata로 뚝딱뚝딱 저자, blog.naver.com/sanzo213 운영
# 갖다 쓰시거나 수정을 하셔도 되지만 출처는 꼭 밝혀주세요
# cols옵션 및 befor/after옵션에 튜플이 가능하게끔 수정했으며, 오류문구 수정함(2021.07.12,1)
# 칼럼이 멀티인덱스인 상태에서 reset_index()메소드 사용했을 시 적용안되는 걸 수정함(2021.07.12,2) 

import pandas as pd
if (type(cols)==str) or (type(cols)==int) or (type(cols)==float) or (type(cols)==bool) or type(cols)==tuple:    
    cols=[cols]
    
dd=list(dataframe.columns)
for i in cols:
    i
    dd.remove(i) #cols요소를 제거함
    
if (f_or_l==None) & ((before==None) & (after==None)):
    print('f_or_l옵션을 쓰시거나 아니면 before옵션/after옵션 쓰셔야되요')
    
if ((f_or_l=='first') or (f_or_l=='last')) & ~((before==None) & (after==None)):
    print('f_or_l옵션 사용시 before after 옵션 사용불가입니다.')
    
if (f_or_l=='first') & (before==None) & (after==None):
    new_order=cols+dd
    dataframe=dataframe[new_order]
    return dataframe

if (f_or_l=='last') & (before==None) & (after==None):   
    new_order=dd+cols
    dataframe=dataframe[new_order]
    return dataframe
    
if (before!=None) & (after!=None):
    print('before옵션 after옵션 둘다 쓸 수 없습니다.')
    

if (before!=None) & (after==None) & (f_or_l==None):

    if not((type(before)==str) or (type(before)==int) or (type(before)==float) or
       (type(before)==bool) or ((type(before)!=list)) or 
       ((type(before)==tuple))):
        print('before옵션은 칼럼 하나만 입력가능하며 리스트 형태로도 입력하지 마세요.')
    
    else:
        b=dd[:dd.index(before)]
        a=dd[dd.index(before):]
        
        new_order=b+cols+a
        dataframe=dataframe[new_order]  
        return dataframe
    
if (after!=None) & (before==None) & (f_or_l==None):

    if not((type(after)==str) or (type(after)==int) or (type(after)==float) or
       (type(after)==bool) or ((type(after)!=list)) or 
       ((type(after)==tuple))):
            
        print('after옵션은 칼럼 하나만 입력가능하며 리스트 형태로도 입력하지 마세요.')  

    else:
        b=dd[:dd.index(after)+1]
        a=dd[dd.index(after)+1:]
        
        new_order=b+cols+a
        dataframe=dataframe[new_order]
        return dataframe
```

python code below is an example of order function I made. I hope you can reorder column(s) so easily with my order function :)

```
# module

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from order import order # call order function from order.py file

# make a dataset

columns='a b c d e f g h i j k'.split()
dic={}

n=-1
for i in columns:
    
    n+=1
    dic[i]=list(range(1+n,10+1+n))
data=pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(data)

# use order function (1) : order column e in the first

data2=order(data,'e',f_or_l='first')
print(data2)

# use order function (2): order column e in the last , "data" dataframe

print(order(data,'e',f_or_l='last'))


# use order function (3) : order column i before column c in "data" dataframe

print(order(data,'i',before='c'))


# use order function (4) : order column g after column b in "data" dataframe

print(order(data,'g',after='b'))

# use order function (4) : order columns ['c', 'd', 'e'] after column i in "data" dataframe

print(order(data,['c', 'd', 'e'],after='i'))
```