# Change the order of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two data-frames

df1

```
Index([u'CASE_NO', u'DECISION_DATE', u'CASE_STATUS', u'APPLICATION_TYPE', u'EMPLOYER_NAME', u'EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_1', u'EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_2', u'EMPLOYER_CITY', u'EMPLOYER_STATE', u'EMPLOYER_POSTAL_CODE', u'2007_NAICS_US_CODE', u'2007_NAICS_US_TITLE', u'US_ECONOMIC_SECTOR', u'PW_SOC_CODE', u'PW_SOC_TITLE', u'PW_JOB_TITLE_9089', u'PW_LEVEL_9089', u'PW_SOURCE_NAME_9089', u'PW_AMOUNT_9089', u'PW_UNIT_OF_PAY_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_FROM_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_TO_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_UNIT_OF_PAY_9089', u'JOB_INFO_WORK_CITY', u'JOB_INFO_WORK_STATE', u'COUNTRY_OF_CITZENSHIP', u'CLASS_OF_ADMISSION'], dtype='object')
```

df2

```
Index([u'CASE_NO', u'DECISION_DATE', u'CASE_STATUS', u'APPLICATION_TYPE', u'EMPLOYER_NAME', u'EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_1', u'EMPLOYER_CITY', u'EMPLOYER_STATE', u'EMPLOYER_POSTAL_CODE', u'2007_NAICS_US_CODE', u'2007_NAICS_US_TITLE', u'US_ECONOMIC_SECTOR', u'PW_SOC_CODE', u'PW_SOC_TITLE', u'PW_JOB_TITLE_9089', u'PW_LEVEL_9089', u'PW_SOURCE_NAME_9089', u'PW_AMOUNT_9089', u'PW_UNIT_OF_PAY_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_FROM_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_TO_9089', u'WAGE_OFFER_UNIT_OF_PAY_9089', u'JOB_INFO_WORK_CITY', u'JOB_INFO_WORK_STATE', u'COUNTRY_OF_CITZENSHIP', u'CLASS_OF_ADMISSION'], dtype='object')
```

I am trying to concat the two dataframes but the columns are not in the same order in both the dataframes. I came across this question [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

and I think I am thinking if there is something else to do more efficiently.

df2 columns should be reordered to match the df1 columns.

Answer (score 2):

If the column names are the same but just in a different order, you can do `df2[df1.columns]`.