# Ordering columns in dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

Recently updated to pandas 0.17.0 and I'm trying to order the columns in my dataframe alphabetically.

Here are the column labels as they currently are:

```
['UX2', 'RHO1', 'RHO3', 'RHO2', 'RHO4', 'UX1', 'UX4', 'UX3']
```

And I want them like this:

```
['RHO1', 'RHO2', 'RHO3', 'RHO4', 'UX1', 'UX2', 'UX3', 'UX4']
```

The only way I've been able to do this is following this from 3 years ago:  [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Is there a built-in way to do this in 0.17.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort the columns alphabetically here, you can just use `sort_index`:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

The method returns a reindexed DataFrame with the columns in the correct order.

This assumes that all of the column labels are strings (it won't work for a mix of, say, strings and integers). If this *isn't* the case, you may need to pass an explicit ordering to the `reindex` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort them and put them back. Suppose you have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, n in enumerate(['UX2', 'RHO1', 'RHO3', 'RHO2', 'RHO4', 'UX1', 'UX4', 'UX3']):
    df[n] = [i]
```

It looks like this:

```
df
   UX2  RHO1  RHO3  RHO2  RHO4  UX1  UX4  UX3
0    0     1     2     3     4    5    6    7
```

Do this:

```
df = df[ sorted(df.columns)]
```

And you should see this:

```
df
   RHO1  RHO2  RHO3  RHO4  UX1  UX2  UX3  UX4
0     1     3     2     4    5    0    7    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of the columns labels in the order you want.

```
cols = ['RHO1', 'RHO2', 'RHO3', 'RHO4', 'UX1', 'UX2', 'UX3', 'UX4']
```

Then assign this order to your DataFrame df:

```
df = df[cols]
```