# Python: how to add a column to a pandas dataframe between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a column to a dataframe between two columns in number labeled columns dataframe. In the following dataframe the first column corresponds to the index while the first row to the name of the columns.

```
df
   0 0 1 2 3 4 5
   1 6 7 4 5 2 1
   2 0 3 1 3 3 4
   3 9 8 4 3 6 2
```

I have `tmp=[2,3,5]` that I want to put between the columns `4` and `5`, so

```
df
   0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
   1 6 7 4 5 2 2 1
   2 0 3 1 3 3 3 4
   3 9 8 4 3 6 5 2
```

Comment: You just need to [add a new column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas) and then [order your columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(4, 'new_col_name', tmp)
```

Note: The `insert` method mutates the original DataFrame and does not return a copy.

If you use `df = df.insert(4, 'new_col_name', tmp)`, `df` will be `None`.

Comment: @RK1 Is there a way to insert a column before a specific column name instead of using the column index?

Comment: @cms72 `insert` doesn't directly support that use case but you can get the column index from column name and pass that: `df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('col_name'), 'new_col_name', ser_to_insert)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: "Note: The insert method mutates the original DataFrame and does not return a copy."  - this heads up is really important, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First concatenate your column to your dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(tmp)], axis=1)
```

Then rename the columns to the desired end result.

```
df2.columns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Now sort on the renamed columns.

```
df2.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

>>> df2
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  6  7  4  5  2  2  1
1  0  3  1  3  3  3  4
2  9  8  4  3  6  5  2
```