# How to reorder certain row index in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
              100MHz_Dif0  102MHz_Dif0  100MHz_Dif1  102MHz_Dif1
Frequency                                                       
9.000000e+07   -70.209000   -65.174004   -66.063004   -66.490997
9.003333e+07   -70.628998   -65.196999   -66.339996   -66.461998
9.006667e+07   -70.405998   -65.761002   -65.432999   -65.549004
9.010000e+07   -70.524002   -65.552002   -66.038002   -65.887001
9.013333e+07   -70.746002   -65.658997   -65.086998   -65.390999
9.016667e+07   -70.884003   -66.209999   -64.887001   -65.397003
9.020000e+07   -70.752998   -66.019997   -65.308998   -66.571999
9.023333e+07   -70.447998   -65.858002   -65.500000   -65.028999
9.026667e+07   -70.452003   -65.832001   -66.032997   -65.005997
9.030000e+07   -71.219002   -65.739998   -65.961998   -65.986000
9.033333e+07   -71.095001   -65.820999   -67.112999   -65.977997
9.036667e+07   -70.834000   -65.926003   -66.348000   -65.568001
```

as an example. If I want to move the third row and forth row to be the first and the second row, which command shall I use? And I will change the order of the rows depending on the frequency, then what can I do to implement it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplication : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns/39237712

Comment: Do you mean columns or rows?  Can you provide what your expected output looks like.  At the moment, I'm confused.  I've provided a way to move the rows. However, I'm very unclear as to what you mean by order the rows by frequency.  You have frequency in you index (which is already sorted) and frequencies in you column headers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I want to is like move 9.003333e+07 this row from the second row to the first row and keep others the same. This is just an example, I may sort the frequency and move the frequency I want to the top rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For change order of index values by `frequency` use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
            100MHz_Dif0  102MHz_Dif0  100MHz_Dif1  102MHz_Dif1
Frequency                                                     
90000000.0   -70.209000   -65.174004   -66.063004   -66.490997
90033330.0   -70.628998   -65.196999   -66.339996   -66.461998
90066670.0   -70.405998   -65.761002   -65.432999   -65.549004
90100000.0   -70.524002   -65.552002   -66.038002   -65.887001
90133330.0   -70.746002   -65.658997   -65.086998   -65.390999
90166670.0   -70.884003   -66.209999   -64.887001   -65.397003
90200000.0   -70.752998   -66.019997   -65.308998   -66.571999
90233330.0   -70.447998   -65.858002   -65.500000   -65.028999
90266670.0   -70.452003   -65.832001   -66.032997   -65.005997
90300000.0   -71.219002   -65.739998   -65.961998   -65.986000
90333330.0   -71.095001   -65.820999   -67.112999   -65.977997
90366670.0   -70.834000   -65.926003   -66.348000   -65.568001
```

And for sort columns:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
            100MHz_Dif0  100MHz_Dif1  102MHz_Dif0  102MHz_Dif1
Frequency                                                     
90000000.0   -70.209000   -66.063004   -65.174004   -66.490997
90033330.0   -70.628998   -66.339996   -65.196999   -66.461998
90066670.0   -70.405998   -65.432999   -65.761002   -65.549004
90100000.0   -70.524002   -66.038002   -65.552002   -65.887001
90133330.0   -70.746002   -65.086998   -65.658997   -65.390999
90166670.0   -70.884003   -64.887001   -66.209999   -65.397003
90200000.0   -70.752998   -65.308998   -66.019997   -66.571999
90233330.0   -70.447998   -65.500000   -65.858002   -65.028999
90266670.0   -70.452003   -66.032997   -65.832001   -65.005997
90300000.0   -71.219002   -65.961998   -65.739998   -65.986000
90333330.0   -71.095001   -67.112999   -65.820999   -65.977997
90366670.0   -70.834000   -66.348000   -65.926003   -65.568001
```

And for sorts both - `index` and `columns`:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1).sort_index()
print (df)
            100MHz_Dif0  100MHz_Dif1  102MHz_Dif0  102MHz_Dif1
Frequency                                                     
90000000.0   -70.209000   -66.063004   -65.174004   -66.490997
90033330.0   -70.628998   -66.339996   -65.196999   -66.461998
90066670.0   -70.405998   -65.432999   -65.761002   -65.549004
90100000.0   -70.524002   -66.038002   -65.552002   -65.887001
90133330.0   -70.746002   -65.086998   -65.658997   -65.390999
90166670.0   -70.884003   -64.887001   -66.209999   -65.397003
90200000.0   -70.752998   -65.308998   -66.019997   -66.571999
90233330.0   -70.447998   -65.500000   -65.858002   -65.028999
90266670.0   -70.452003   -66.032997   -65.832001   -65.005997
90300000.0   -71.219002   -65.961998   -65.739998   -65.986000
90333330.0   -71.095001   -67.112999   -65.820999   -65.977997
90366670.0   -70.834000   -66.348000   -65.926003   -65.568001
```

Comment: I was going to post that too.  But I'm just confused.  Why would you want to move 3rd and 4th rows to 1st and 2nd just to sort?

Comment: I dont know too. So rather add both solutions.

Comment: Maybe add `df.sort_index(axis=1).sort_index()` as well.  Cover all the bases.

Comment: Good luck!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you dataframe is named `df`
Use [**`np.r_`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to create the appropriate slice

```
df.iloc[np.r_[[2, 3], [0, 1], 4:]]

                100MHz_Dif0  102MHz_Dif0  100MHz_Dif1  102MHz_Dif1
Frequency                                                     
90066670.0   -70.405998   -65.761002   -65.432999   -65.549004
90100000.0   -70.524002   -65.552002   -66.038002   -65.887001
90000000.0   -70.209000   -65.174004   -66.063004   -66.490997
90033330.0   -70.628998   -65.196999   -66.339996   -66.461998
90000000.0   -70.209000   -65.174004   -66.063004   -66.490997
90033330.0   -70.628998   -65.196999   -66.339996   -66.461998
90066670.0   -70.405998   -65.761002   -65.432999   -65.549004
90100000.0   -70.524002   -65.552002   -66.038002   -65.887001
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I do not what is the exact row index, instead, I know the frequency like 9010000.0 or 9003330.0, is there any any to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This can be practical since you have only 4 columns
assuming the dataFrame do:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame[['100MHz_Dif1','102MHz_Dif1','100MHz_Dif0', '102MHz_Dif0']]
```

which is actually rewriting the dataFrame,