# Multi dimension Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, scikit-learn

I have just started learning Machine learning and Scikit. I have been watching a tutorial in which the person used Quandl to fetch data for google stock prices. As far as I have researched, Quandl.get returns pandas dataframe. What's confusing about this dataframe for me is, a piece of code is adding columns in *second dimension of the dataframe and on another line the tutor is accessing the same column using the FIRST dimension of the dataframe*. How is that possible? What's going on with this dataframe?

```
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]

df['HCL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] # how is df['Adj. Open'] working?? Wasn't 'Adj. Open' added in the second dimension of the dataframe in the second line of the code above??
```

My goal is to learn Tensorflow and have a little bit of knowledge about Machine learning slangs and concepts before I dive into TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I add `df.head()` to write output for showing data:

```
#read data
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print (df.head())
              Open    High     Low    Close      Volume  Ex-Dividend  \
Date                                                                   
2004-08-19  100.01  104.06   95.96  100.335  44659000.0          0.0   
2004-08-20  101.01  109.08  100.50  108.310  22834300.0          0.0   
2004-08-23  110.76  113.48  109.05  109.400  18256100.0          0.0   
2004-08-24  111.24  111.60  103.57  104.870  15247300.0          0.0   
2004-08-25  104.76  108.00  103.88  106.000   9188600.0          0.0   

            Split Ratio  Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  \
Date                                                                   
2004-08-19          1.0  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842   
2004-08-20          1.0  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689   
2004-08-23          1.0  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377   
2004-08-24          1.0  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363   
2004-08-25          1.0  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113   

            Adj. Volume  
Date                     
2004-08-19   44659000.0  
2004-08-20   22834300.0  
2004-08-23   18256100.0  
2004-08-24   15247300.0  
2004-08-25    9188600.0
```

---

```
#select data by columns (filter) and set order of columns 
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
print (df.head())
            Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume
Date                                                                
2004-08-19  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842   44659000.0
2004-08-20  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689   22834300.0
2004-08-23  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377   18256100.0
2004-08-24  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363   15247300.0
2004-08-25  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113    9188600.0

#count data - select by columns
df['HCL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open']
print (df.head())
            Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume   HCL_PCT
Date                                                                          
2004-08-19  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842   44659000.0  0.003250
2004-08-20  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689   22834300.0  0.072270
2004-08-23  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377   18256100.0 -0.012279
2004-08-24  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363   15247300.0 -0.057264
2004-08-25  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113    9188600.0  0.011837
```

Select column `Adj. Close`:

```
print (df['Adj. Close'])
Date
2004-08-19     50.322842
2004-08-20     54.322689
2004-08-23     54.869377
2004-08-24     52.597363
2004-08-25     53.164113
2004-08-26     54.122070
2004-08-27     53.239345
2004-08-30     51.162935
2004-08-31     51.343492
2004-09-01     50.280210
2004-09-02     50.912161
2004-09-03     50.159839
2004-09-07     50.947269
2004-09-08     51.308384
2004-09-09     51.313400
2004-09-10     52.828075
2004-09-13     53.916435
2004-09-14     55.917612
2004-09-15     56.173402
2004-09-16     57.161452
2004-09-17     58.926902
2004-09-20     59.864797
2004-09-21     59.102444
2004-09-22     59.373280
2004-09-23     60.597057
2004-09-24     60.100525
2004-09-27     59.313094
2004-09-28     63.626409
2004-09-29     65.742942
2004-09-30     65.000651

2017-04-13    840.180000
2017-04-17    855.130000
2017-04-18    853.990000
2017-04-19    856.510000
2017-04-20    860.080000
2017-04-21    858.950000
2017-04-24    878.930000
2017-04-25    888.840000
2017-04-26    889.140000
2017-04-27    891.440000
2017-04-28    924.520000
2017-05-01    932.820000
2017-05-02    937.090000
2017-05-03    948.450000
2017-05-04    954.720000
2017-05-05    950.280000
2017-05-08    958.690000
2017-05-09    956.710000
2017-05-10    954.840000
2017-05-11    955.890000
2017-05-12    955.140000
2017-05-15    959.220000
2017-05-16    964.610000
2017-05-17    942.170000
2017-05-18    950.500000
2017-05-19    954.650000
2017-05-22    964.070000
2017-05-23    970.550000
2017-05-24    977.610000
2017-05-25    991.860000
Name: Adj. Close, Length: 3215, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'D':[4,5,6],
                   'B':[7,8,9],
                   'F':[1,3,5],
                   'C':[5,3,6]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  F
0  1  7  5  4  1
1  2  8  3  5  3
2  3  9  6  6  5

#select only columns A,B,C and return new dataframe in new order of columns
df1 = df[['A','B','C']]
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  7  5
1  2  8  3
2  3  9  6

#select only columns A,B,C and return new dataframe in new order of columns
df2 = df[['C','A','B']]
print (df2)
   C  A  B
0  5  1  7
1  3  2  8
2  6  3  9
```

Comment: Shouldn't df['Adj. Open'] return garbage value or throw error altogether because it was declared in the second dimension of the Pandas DataFrame list on the second line of the code?

Comment: No, it only select data - return `Series` (column). I can multiple  select it.

Comment: Second column only select all possible columns and assign back to df

Comment: and third select only 3 columns separately for subtract and division.

Comment: I don't understand. `df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]` is declaring `Adj. Open` in the `2nd` dimension of the dataframe. So how can we access `Adj. Open` like `df[Adj. Open]`. It makes no sense

Comment: No, you are wrong. It only reorder columns, not set `2d` division.

Comment: It is same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741480/2901002)

Comment: Coming from Java, Javascript, C I have learned that this way a 2nd dimension list/array is defined. Can you please point me to a simple tutorial that explains how  this `df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]` notation is working

Comment: Maybe help [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) - maybe from `In [9]: df` to `Attribute Access`.

Comment: Can you please point me to a tutorial that shows how df[ [] ] is handled behind the scenes for reordering in Simple PYTHON without Pandas?

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible get reoerdering in python. Becasue if use `df[[ ]]` call pandas function - it is called subset - it simply select only specified columns and return new dataframe with new order.

Comment: I try add to answer another sample, maybe it help you better understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

index : Index or array-like

in Dataframe structure, the use of an index to obtain a column, the use of an array or a number of queues, the equivalent of df [:, []](all selected elements, column elements slice access)