# Pandas Pivot Table manually sort columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot-table

For a given data frame:

```
UUT                  testa  testb  testc  testd
DateTime                                
2017-11-21 18:47:29    1.0    1.0    1.0    3.0
2017-11-21 18:47:30    1.0    2.0    1.0    4.0
2017-11-21 18:47:31    1.0    2.0    5.0    2.0
2017-11-21 18:47:32    1.0    2.0    5.0    1.0
2017-11-21 18:47:33    1.0    2.0    5.0    4.0
2017-11-21 18:47:34    1.0    2.0    5.0    1.0
```

how can I manually rearrange the columns anyway I want it
for example if I want to the following sequence:

```
testc, testd, testa, testb
```

So the table and the plot will be in this way:

```
UUT                  testc  testd  testa  testb  
DateTime                                         
2017-11-21 18:47:29    1.0    3.0    1.0    1.0  
2017-11-21 18:47:30    1.0    4.0    1.0    2.0  
2017-11-21 18:47:31    5.0    2.0    1.0    2.0  
2017-11-21 18:47:32    5.0    1.0    1.0    2.0  
2017-11-21 18:47:33    5.0    4.0    1.0    2.0  
2017-11-21 18:47:34    5.0    1.0    1.0    2.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns

Comment: There is an answer for you right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.reindex_axis(['testc','testd', 'testa','testb'], axis=1)
```