# Shuffling a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [pd.Timestamp(2015,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2015,1,3), pd.Timestamp(2015,4,1), pd.Timestamp(2015,11,1)]
quantities = [1, 16, 9, 4]
e_quantities = [1, 4, 3, 2]
data = dict(quantities=quantities, e_quantities=e_quantities)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=data.keys(), index=timestamps)
```

which looks like this:

```
            quantities  e_quantities
2015-01-01           1             1
2015-01-03          16             4
2015-04-01           9             3
2015-11-01           4             2
```

I want to shuffle all of the columns *except* the `index` one but keeping all the rows matching. I've done this:

```
import numpy as np
indices_scrambled = np.arange(0, len(timestamps))
np.random.shuffle(indices_scrambled)
df.quantities = df.quantities.values[indices_scrambled]
df.e_quantities = df.e_quantities.values[indices_scrambled]
```

which works and produces:

```
            quantities  e_quantities
2015-01-01          16             4
2015-01-03           9             3
2015-04-01           1             1
2015-11-01           4             2
```

but doesn't extend well if I add lots of columns as I have to keep writing `df.column_1 = df.column_1.values[indices_scrambled`, `df.column_2 = df.column_2.values[indices_scrambled`, etc.

**Is there a way to scramble all of the columns in the data frame at once, except for the index one?**

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: scramble the columns means to shuffle the order of the columns at random? like if order was `[1,2,3,4,5]` you would like something like `[2,5,1,4,3]`?

Comment: @Yuca Exactly -- but keep the index values the same after that

Comment: you have two answers, but this might help you too https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935892/9754169

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
index = df.index
df = shuffle(df)
df.index = index
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it uses the same `np.random.shuffle()` in a loop over columns:

```
for col in df.columns.to_list():
     np.random.shuffle(df[col])

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted was to keep the the rows matched but their order and keep the index as it was in the begging. Taking your example: `for col in df.columns.to_list():
    df[col].values[:] = df[col][indices_scrambled].values` achieves this, but it's quite verbose!