# Arrange the columns(month) in ascending order

Tags: python, dataframe

**1/ Original data in excel**

I have a data frame with these data values as shown below:
[image]

**2/ Coding**

Loading this excel into a data frame, wrote a pivot_table code to index the category and display the count of transactions for each month.

This is the code:

```
loadexpense_df = pd.read_excel("C:ExpensesTestData.xlsx")
month_df = pd.pivot_table(loadexpense_df,index="Category",columns="Month",aggfunc={"Month":len}, fill_value=0)
```

The result of month_df as shown below:
[image]

**3/ Question**

I would want to arrange the month colunms in this order: Feb, Mar, Apr and so on. Is this possible to do?

Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Does your column has names as Feb, Mar, Apr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see your current columns:

```py
cols = month_df.columns.tolist()
```

I think your `cols` should be like this now:

```py
[('Month', 'Apr'), ('Month', 'Aug'), ...]
```

so you can reorder your `cols` like this:

```py
month_names = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
cols = sorted(cols, key=lambda x: month_names.index(x[1]))
```

and finally set the months_df with new columns ordering:

```py
month_df = month_df[cols]
```

And I think its done.

You can read more about reordering columns in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Took some time to understand the lamda syntax and manage to wrote a 3 lines code to get same result as lamda. Good one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC :

You need to reindex the axis in the order you want. There is a method known as `reindex_axis`

I am assuming you have the name of the columns :

**IF NO :**

```
column_list = month_df.columns.tolist()
```

Access the month name using :

```
column_list.index(x[1])
```

**If YES**

```
order_of_column = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']

month_df1 = month_df.reindex_axis(order_of_column, axis=1)
```