# Pandas reverse order of some columns not all

Tags: python, pandas

There are a few solutions to reverse the order of all columns here on SO like for example so:

`df = df.iloc[:,::-1]`

What I want to achieve is only reverse the order of columns starting from column 2 on, so I want to keep A and B in the same place and only reverse the order of the columns after that. As I have a couple of hundred columns and don't want to write the order manually.

My initial columns are:

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|
```

And The Result I am looking for is:

```
| A | B | F | E | D | C |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[list(df.columns[:2]) + list(df.columns[:1:-1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concatenate of indices and tehn select by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCDEF'))

print (df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:2, len(df.columns)-1:1:-1]])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, F, E, D, C]
Index: []
```

Or seelct both `DataFrame`s with `join`:

```
print (df.iloc[:, :2].join(df.iloc[:, :1:-1]))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, F, E, D, C]
Index: []
```