# How to re-order a csv file without headers in Python?

Tags: python, csv, file

How can one re-order a CSV without headers. Please note that the CSV file has around 100 thousands records.

Example of the CSV file:

```
1,$1,AA,GG,DD
2,$2,A1,FD,HH
3,$3,1A,PP,LL
4,$4,1G,LL,SS
```

Expected output:

```
DD,GG,1,$1,AA
HH,FD,2,$2,A1
LL,PP,3,$3,1A
SS,LL,4,$4,1G
```

Thank you all. PLEASE NOTE; Im using Windows

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns) might answer your question. Yeah one more thing, you can read a csv as a dataframe using `pd.read_csv()` and then rewrite back using `df.to_csv('filename')`. the documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

Comment: you can do that with `awk`

Comment: @AnuragReddy im not sure if thats the right thing to do with so much records. Walter Tross, how is that done with awk?

Comment: `awk -F, '{ printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $5, $4, $1, $2, $3 }' filename.csv`

Comment: @NorthAfrican, oh sorry I missed the statement showing 100k records. The solution by Walter Tross is very efficient then.

Comment: @WalterTross You need to tell me what you did there lol....

Comment: just basic usage, see `man awk`.`-F` is the field separator (the default is whitespace). Of course, if you had commas within quotes in your csv this wouldn't work.

Comment: @WalterTross what if my file is tab seperated?

Comment: `awk -F'\t' '{ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $5, $4, $1, $2, $3 }' filename.csv`, but you don't need the `-F` if you don't have spaces within fields. Furthermore I have tried it on my Mac with `zsh`, not sure about other envs. It shouls work, though, since the separator probably should not be interpreted by the shell, and be interpreted as a regex by `awk`

Comment: @WalterTross if I copy paste your line I get `invalid syntax`

Comment: funny, can't help any further, today, sorry

Comment: @WalterTross awk is not usable for Windows lol....

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below program. This reads through the input file, split it with comma, reorder it and write into output file delimited with comma.

```py
with open("input.csv","r") as f, open("output.csv","w") as f1:
    for line in f:
        cols=line.strip().split(",")
        f1.write(",".join([cols[4],cols[3]]+cols[:3])+"\n")
```

**Output**

```
DD,GG,1,$1,AA
HH,FD,2,$2,A1
LL,PP,3,$3,1A
SS,LL,4,$4,1G
```

Comment: what if my file is tab seperated?

Comment: Replace comma with `\t`

Answer (score 1):

I've played a bit with your question and here's what I came up with:

```
import csv
import time


traget_file = "1000000_Sales_Records.csv"
output_file = "swapped.csv"
new_order = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 7, 10, 8, 13, 11, 12]
delim = ","


def read_data(filename: str, delim: str):
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delim)
        next(datareader, None)  # skip header
        for row in datareader:
            yield row


def swapper(file, order):
    for row in read_data(file, delim):
        yield [row[index - 1] for index in order]


with open(output_file, "a") as nf:
    w = csv.writer(nf)
    s = time.time()
    for new_row in swapper(traget_file, new_order):
        w.writerow(new_row)
    e = time.time()
    print(f"Done in {round((e - s) / 60, 2)}")
```

I've tested this with a sample `.csv` file with `1000000` rows and it swapped the order in about `13` seconds. I've taken the file from [here](http://eforexcel.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1000000%20Sales%20Records.zip).

This works both with comma and tab delimited `.csv` files. Just change the `","` to `"\t"` if you want to work with a tab delimited file.