# How to reorder the first n dataframe columns, and add remaining columns at the end?

Tags: python, pandas

Unpredictably formatted `df`:

```
  First Name  number last_name
0    Cthulhu     666     Smith
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Cthulhu'], 'number': [666], 'last_name': ['Smith']})
```

This needs to be put into column names and order: `TemplateColumns = ['First Name', 'other', 'number']`. If columns don't exist they can be created:

```
for col in TemplateColumns:
    if col not in df:
        df[col] = np.nan
```

Which gives:

```
  First Name  number last_name  other
0    Cthulhu     666     Smith    NaN
```

And initial columns need to be ordered the same as `TemplateColumns`, leaving the remaining columns at the end, to get `desired_df`:

```
  First Name  other   number last_name
0    Cthulhu    NaN      666     Smith

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Cthulhu'], 'other': [np.nan], 'number': [666], 'last_name': ['Smith']})
```

Reordering columns is [well explained in other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns), but I don't know how to order the first n columns and keep the rest at the end. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cols = TemplateColumns + df.columns.difference(TemplateColumns, sort=False).tolist()
df_final =  df.reindex(cols, axis=1)

Out[714]:
  First Name  other  number last_name
0    Cthulhu    NaN     666     Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to achieve this. Essentially you can use `.reindex()` to reorder the dataframe while including empty columns if they don't exist. The only remaining part to figure out would be how to add the remaining columns not in `TemplateColumns` to your dataframe. You can do this by obtaining the set difference of the column index from the `TemplateColumns` then updating the order before your call to `.reindex`

Set up data & function

```
def reordered(df, new_order, include_remaining=True):
    cols_to_end = []
    if include_remaining:
        # gets the items in `df.columns` that are NOT in `new_order` 
        cols_to_end = df.columns.difference(new_order, sort=False)
    
    # Ensures that the new_order items are first
    final_order = new_order + list(cols_to_end)
    return df.reindex(columns=final_order)

df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Cthulhu'], 'number': [666], 'last_name': ['Smith']})
new_order = ['First Name', 'other', 'number']
```

with `include_remaining`:

```
out = reordered(df, new_order, include_remaining=True)

print(out)
  First Name  other  number last_name
0    Cthulhu    NaN     666     Smith
```

without `include_remaining`:

```
out = reordered(df, new_order, include_remaining=False)

print(out)
  First Name  other  number
0    Cthulhu    NaN     666
```

Comment: Works well but @andy-l's solution is more elegant. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) like this:

```
for col in TemplateColumns:
    if col not in df:
        df.insert(1, col, np.nan)
```

Comment: @ChrisDixon No problem, don't forget to accept and upvote tho 

Comment: Deleted 1st comment as realized your suggestion didn't fix the problem. The 2nd column needs to be 'other'.

Comment: @ChrisDixon change your `TemplateColumns = ['First Name', 'other', 'numbers']` to `TemplateColumns = ['First Name', 'other', 'number']`

Comment: I've fixed the 'numbers' typo, and although that works for this simplified example, that only leaves the columns in the correct order by coincidence. The columns need to be reordered.