# Export JSON results to CSV using Pandas package

Tags: python, json, pandas, screen-scraping

I am trying to modify the following code (I am newbie at python, so try to teach me step by step)

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd

class AjaxScraper():
    results = []

    def fetch(self, url):
        return requests.get(url)
    
    def parse(self, content):
        self.results = content['data']
                
        for entry in self.results:
            del entry['_id']
    
    def to_csv(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.results)
        pd.to_csv('Table.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False)
    
    def start_me(self):
        response = self.fetch('https://scrapingkungfu.herokuapp.com/api?_=1576384789999')
        self.parse(response.json())
        self.to_csv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = AjaxScraper()
    scraper.start_me()
```

I have got errors like that

```
  File "demo.py", line 24, in start_me
    self.to_csv()
  File "demo.py", line 19, in to_csv
    pd.to_csv('Table.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I wonder why this error appears although I saw many codes that has `to_csv` in pandas package..!!

** This is a simple dataframe that I need to learn how to reorder the columns using the index of columns

```
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'Score': [90,80,95,20]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

print (df)
```

Comment: I have figured it out after posting the problem using this instead `df.to_csv('Table.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Do I need to delete my answer

Comment: No sir. I will mark it as answered. Question: it is possible to reorder the columns of the data frame or delete specific columns ..? can you guide me with simple examples?

Comment: Ah Yasser Bro.  We can reorder the dataframes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I feel lost as I can't get most of the answers. Can you post a simple example with a simple data frame of three columns and show me how to reorder using the index of columns, not the headers?

Comment: I have attached simple example of dataframe. I need to understand not just to solve the problem.

Comment: I know the stackoverflow answer may be complicated So https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to_csv is a method of a DataFrame object, not of the pandas module.
You need to create a dataframe

## Reordering the Dataframe with your example

```
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'Score': [90,80,95,20]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

print (df)
```

[image]

1. The solution is creating a new data frame with our desired order

```
df = df[['Score', 'Name']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already recognized that point just before seeing your great answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any chance to order using the columns index .. I mean to use an array of the desired numbers of columns?

Comment: I have searched and found a way using indexes like that `print(df[df.columns[[1,0]]])`. Thanks a lot for your support.