# sort headers by specific cols - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I'm trying to sort col headers by last 3 columns only. Using below, `sort_index` works on the whole data frame but not when I select the last 3 cols only.

Note: I can't hard-code the sorting because I don't know the columns headers beforehand.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Z' : [1,1,1,1,1],  
    'B' : ['A','A','A','A','A'],                  
    'C' : ['B','A','A','A','A'], 
    'A' : [5,6,6,5,5],                         
    })

# sorts all cols
df = df.sort_index(axis = 1)

# aim to sort by last 3 cols
#df.iloc[:,1:3] = df.iloc[:,1:3].sort_index(axis=1)
```

Intended Out:

```
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  A  B  5
1  1  A  A  6
2  1  A  A  6
3  1  A  A  5
4  1  A  A  5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns). Gives you a couple of options for ways to go about this

Comment: No it doesn't. I've re-arranged the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
out = df.reindex(columns=df.columns[[0]].tolist()+sorted(df.columns[1:].tolist()))
Out[66]: 
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  5  A  B
1  1  6  A  A
2  1  6  A  A
3  1  5  A  A
4  1  5  A  A
```

Method two `insert`

```
newdf = df.iloc[:,1:].sort_index(axis=1)
newdf.insert(loc=0, column='Z', value=df.Z)
newdf
Out[74]: 
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  5  A  B
1  1  6  A  A
2  1  6  A  A
3  1  5  A  A
4  1  5  A  A
```

Comment: sorry, I'll re-word question. I need to pass a function that doesn't know the col headers in advance

Comment: Brilliant. Why wasn't the original function working?

Comment: @jonboy when you assign the value pandas still match the index and column , so your sort function does not work