# Strange Behavior With Pandas Group By - Transform On String Columns

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I encountered a strange behavior with Pandas **.groupby()** with **.transform()**. Here is the code to generate the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] ,
                   "Random_Number": [1223344, 373293832, 32738382392, 7273283232, 8239329, 23938832],
                   "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]})
```

This is the function I wrote for the transform().

```
# this function will attach each value in string col with the number of elements in the each city group
# if the col type is not an object, then return 0 for all rows. 

def some(x): 
    if x.dtype == 'object':
        return x + '--' + str(len(x))
    else:
        return 0
```

Then I used my function with transform - works flawlessly and get what I want.

```
df_2 = stack.groupby(["City"])['Name','Random_Number'].transform(some)
```

[image]

**HOWEVER, the strange thing happens when I switch the order of the col from `['Name','Random_Number']` to `['Random_Number','Name']`**

```
df_2 = stack.groupby(["City"])['Random_Number','Name'].transform(some)
```

[image]

When you look at cells in the `'Name'` column it seems like pandas puts everything into one cell multiple times:

```
df_2.iloc[0,1]
# Return: 
# 0      Alice--4
# 1        Bob--4
# 3    Mallory--4
# 4        Bob--4
# Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: That's not how you change column order. For example `df = df[df.columns[new_order]]` from answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/5660315 will do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, it definitely helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `return`.

if `x.dtype == 'object'` then you return a Series so your `transform` aggregation **does not reduce** (the return is the same length as the original). If it takes the other path the return is the single scalar `0`, which pandas sees as a reduction (return is a single value per group).

Because your aggregation differs in reduction whatever internals `pandas` uses to figure out the path to take and how to bring that back to the original DataFrame gets confused based on your column ordering. When `'Random_Number'` is first, it checks the function, sees that the function reduces and takes one path, but if `'Name'` comes first it checks, sees the function doesn't reduce and takes another path to compute.

You can fix this by ensuring that both returns **do not reduce**

```
def some(x): 
    if x.dtype == 'object':
        return x + '--' + str(len(x))
    else:
        return [0]*len(x)

df.groupby('City')[['Random_Number','Name']].transform(some)
#   Random_Number        Name
#0              0    Alice--4
#1              0      Bob--4
#2              0  Mallory--2
#3              0  Mallory--4
#4              0      Bob--4
#5              0  Mallory--2

df.groupby('City')[['Name', 'Random_Number']].transform(some)
#         Name  Random_Number
#0    Alice--4              0
#1      Bob--4              0
#2  Mallory--2              0
#3  Mallory--4              0
#4      Bob--4              0
#5  Mallory--2              0
```

Comment: Wow, that is the reason! thank you so much! Now I got it!