# Applying regex to pandas column based on different pos of same character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'text_1':['value: 1.25MG - OM - PO/TUBE - ashaf', 'value:2.5 MG - OM - PO/TUBE -test','value: 18 UNITS(S)','value: 850 MG - TDS AFTER FOOD - SC (SUBCUTANEOUS) -had', 'value: 75 MG - OM - PO/TUBE']})
```

I would like to apply regex and create two columns based on rules given below

col `val` should store all text after `value:` and before `first hyphen`

col `Adm` should store all text after `third hyphen`

I tried the below but it doesn't work accurately

```
tdf['text_1'].str.findall('[.0-9]+\s*[mgMG/lLcCUNIT]+')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```py
tdf[["val", "Adm"]] = tdf["text_1"].str.extract(r'^val:\s*([^-]*?)(?:\s*-[^-]*-\s*(.*))?$', expand=True)
# => >>> tdf
                                             text_1          val  \
0                        val: 1.25MG - OM - PO/TUBE       1.25MG   
1                         val:2.5 MG - OM - PO/TUBE       2.5 MG   
2                                  val: 18 UNITS(S)  18 UNITS(S)   
3  val: 850 MG - TDS AFTER FOOD - SC (SUBCUTANEOUS)       850 MG   
4                         val: 75 MG - OM - PO/TUBE        75 MG   


0            PO/TUBE  
1            PO/TUBE  
2                NaN  
3  SC (SUBCUTANEOUS)  
4            PO/TUBE
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZTTzb3/1).

*Details*:

- `^val:` - `val:` at the start of string (if `val:` is not always at the start of the string, remove `^` anchor)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^-]*?)` - Group 1: any chars other than `-` as few as possible
- `(?:\s*-[^-]*-\s*(.*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `-[^-]*-` - a `-`, any zero or more chars other than `-`, and then a `-`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: one minor question. Let's say if I wish to reorder the columns. Meaning, `Adm` should come first and `val` as the last column. Would the regex remain the same?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't try as I am away from my desk

Comment: @TheGreat After extracting, you can [reorder the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns), add the `tdf = tdf[['text_1', 'Adm', 'val']]` line.

Comment: Thanks, one last question. I am trying to change your regex to pick all text after `3rd hyphen` but before `4th hyphen`... So, I write the below `tdf["text_1"].str.extract(r'^value:\s*([^-]*?)(?:\s*-[^-]*-\s*(.*))?[^-]*', expand=True)` but that seems to give incorrect output. would you be able to help?

Comment: @TheGreat That will be `^val:\s*([^-]*?)(?:\s*-[^-]*-\s*([^-]*))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZTTzb3/2).

Answer (score 9):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
tdf[["val", "Adm"]] = tdf["text_1"].str.extract(r'^value:\s?(\S+(?:\s[^-]+)?)(?:\s-\s.*?-([^-]*)(?:-.*)?)?$', expand=True)
tdf
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/kRRGW9/1)

Output will be as follows.

```
                                                    text_1          val                  Adm
0                     value: 1.25MG - OM - PO/TUBE - ashaf       1.25MG             PO/TUBE 
1                        value:2.5 MG - OM - PO/TUBE -test       2.5 MG             PO/TUBE 
2                                       value: 18 UNITS(S)  18 UNITS(S)                  NaN
3  value: 850 MG - TDS AFTER FOOD - SC (SUBCUTANEOUS) -had       850 MG   SC (SUBCUTANEOUS) 
4                              value: 75 MG - OM - PO/TUBE        75 MG              PO/TUBE
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^value:\s?       ##Checking if value starts from value: space is optional here.
(\S+             ##Starting 1st capturing group from here and matching all non space here.
  (?:\s[^-]+)?   ##In a non-capturing group matching space till - comes keeping it optional.
)                ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
(?:\s-\s.*?-     ##In a non-capturing group matching space-space till - first occurrence.
  ([^-]*)        ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has values till next - here.
  (?:-.*)?       ##In a non capturing group from - till end of value keeping it optional.
)?$              ##Closing non-capturing group at the end of the value here.
```

Comment: @TheGreat, could you please do let me know for which samples it doesn't work. With your shown samples its working fine for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you read my comment on the previous answer. I updated my sample dataframe now.

Comment: @TheGreat, with your latest changes(df) when I test `tdf[["val", "Adm"]] = tdf["text_1"].str.extract(r'^value:\s?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?(?:\S+)?)(?:\s-[^-]*-(.*))?$', expand=True)` my bonus solution it works fine for me, let me know on same please.

Comment: Sorry, bonus solution doesn't work with the updated sample

Answer (score 9):

#### [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
tdf['text_1'].str.extract(r'^value:\s?([^-]+)(?:\s-.*?-\s)?([^-]*)(?:\s|$)')
```

---

```
             0                  1
0       1.25MG            PO/TUBE
1       2.5 MG            PO/TUBE
2  18 UNITS(S)                   
3       850 MG  SC (SUBCUTANEOUS)
4        75 MG            PO/TUBE
```

**Regex details:**

- `^` : Assert position at start of line
- `value:` : Matches character sequence `value:`
- `\s?`: Matches any whitespace character between zero and one time
- `([^-]+)` : First capturing group matches any character except `-` one or more times
- `(?:\s-.*?-\s)?` : Non capturing group match between zero and one time

  - `\s`: Matches single whitespace character
  - `-` : Matches character `-`
  - `.*?` : Matches any character between zero and unlimited times but as few times as possible
  - `-` : Matches character `-`
  - `\s` : Matches single whitespace character
- `([^-]*)` : Second capturing group matches any character except `-` zero or more times
- `(?:\s|$)` : Non capturing group

  - `\s-` : Matches single whitespace character
  - `|` : Or switch
  - `$` : Assert position at the end of line

[`See the online Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/XUixSS/1)