# File's style corrupts while converting from xls to xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

I have .xls excel file. I'm converting it to xlsx by;

```
df = panda.read_excel(currentPath)
df.to_excel(currentPath+ 'x')
```

But this messes with the file, columns and rows are changing place, is there a way to convert xls to xlsx without changing anything?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: pandas itself cannot handle 97-03 xls. it's far more than just the file extension.

Comment: @LeiYang thanks for the answer, will change the way I handle then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas isn't primarily intended for manipulating Excel files, and XLS and XLSX are separate formats, not just differences in [naming convention](https://blog.fileformat.com/2019/09/10/xls-vs-xlsx/#:%7E:text=XLS%20files%20are%20based%20on,per%20XLS%20File%20Format%20Specifications.&text=In%20contrast%2C%20an%20XLSX%20file,XML%20files%20in%20ZIP%20format). Because DataFrames aren't intended to represent either XLS or XLSX format, you're juggling three different formats, and the format change might be in either XLS -> DF or DF -> XLSX. That suggests that you probably should not use Pandas DataFrames for this task. If you need to do *other* manipulations with Pandas DF, then you can look into reordering [DF columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns).

Assuming you're *really* trying to reformat the files and do Excel-style manipulations, I recommend [openpyxl, although there are a few competing libraries you might also find useful](https://www.python-excel.org/).  (Also, as @lei-yang notes below, openpyxl may not be able to read XLS files - although other packages listed there should be able to do so.)

If you're not doing any manipulations of the file itself, and don't care about having the file names match the internal formats, the [Python `os` and `shutil` libraries can cover that](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/copy+a+file+and+rename+it+python).

Comment: in the page you pasted, `xlrd` and `xlwt` is better than `openpyxl`. because the OP wants to convert xls to xlsx format.