# Order columns in dataframe based on values from a set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like this

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4
1  a  a  b  b 
2  x  f  f  a
```

How can I order it with a based on values from a set such as

setorder = ('1','3','2','4')

yields

```
id v1 v3 v2 v4
1  a  b  a  b 
2  x  f  f  a
```

Thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/1328439

Comment: First of all, set is a collection which is unordered. Instead you'll have to use tuple or list. And also without trying by yourself asking for a solution directly is not a good practice here on stackoverflow. Kindly refrain doing this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Set is not ordered, so is possible use `tuple` like in sample data:

```
tupleorder = ('1','3','2','4')

df1 = df[['id'] + [f'v{x}' for x in tupleorder]]
print (df1)
   id v1 v3 v2 v4
0   1  a  b  a  b
1   2  x  f  f  a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cols = ('1','3','2','4')
cols = [f"v{x}" for x in cols]
df[cols]
```

Print out:

```
    v1  v3  v2  v4
0   a   b   a   b
1   x   f   f   a
```

You alternatively can use a list for `cols` which is ordered as well.