# Reordering and reverting the last n elements of a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reverse the n last rows and columns in a dataframe in python.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(15), columns=range(15))
```

However, I want to change the dataframe that it looks like this:

```
#columns:
0 1 2 3 ... 10 15 14 13 12 11

#rows: 
0 1 2 3 ... 10 15 14 13 12 11
```

i.e.: the last 5 elements of rows and columns should be reversed but the primer 10 should have the 'normal' form

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns/51935892#51935892

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try

```py
n = 10

df.columns = df.columns[:n+1].append(df.columns[:-(df.shape[1]-n):-1])
df.index = df.index[:n+1].append(df.index[:-(df.shape[0]-n):-1])
# or if you also want to change the content when revert
out = df.loc[df.index[:n+1].append(df.index[:-(df.shape[0]-n):-1]),
             df.columns[:n+1].append(df.columns[:-(df.shape[1]-n):-1])]
```

```
print(df)

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   14   13   12   11
0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: thank you.
I have used:
```
df.index = df.columns[:8].append(df.index[:-8:-1])
```
 It worked, however the data in the dataframe is not moving correspondingly.

Comment: @HansSprungfeld Do you try the `or` part?