# how to change the column numbers of excel in panda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a record of n columns after some changes the last 3 columns should be on the first three columns how can I change them
I know how to swap the columns:
title[1],title[2]= title[2],title[1]
But I want to change the order of entire column(with values)
Foreg:
Srno.|FullName|Phone.no|EmailId|City|State|Country|FirstName|MiddleName|Lastname

i want the out put to be

Srno.|FirstName|MiddleName|Lastname|Phone.no|EmailId|City|State|Country

Comment: Define your answer in a clear way. So community can help you.

Comment: Do you just want to change the name or also the values?

Answer (score 0):

You want to reorder the columns In Excel? If It so then you can refer this code.

```
df=df[["Srno.","FirstName","MiddleName","Lastname","Phone.no","EmailId","City","State","Country"]]
```

You can also refer [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)