# Changing the order of indecs and corresponding rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:
[image]

and I want to change the order of index items so that the last row becomes the first row and then I get all the `NaN` values in the diagonal. I tried the `reindex` function but what I got was basically changing the order of indeces without changing the order of corresponding rows:

```
df.reindex(['T2S1', 'T2S2', 'T2S3', 'T2S4', 'T2O1', 'T2O2', 'T2O3', 'T2O4', 'T2SF1', 'T2SF2', 'T2SF3', 'T2OF1', 'T2OF2', 'T2OF3'])
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
idx = df.index
df.reindex(idx[-1:].append(idx[0:-1]))
```