# How to rearrange the following pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
  |  A   | B   | C   | D   | tag |
0 |  0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 1.0 | a   |
1 |  0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 1.0 | b   |
2 |  0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 1.0 | c   |
```

Is there a way to transform it to the following:

```
tag |  a  |  b  |  c  |
A   | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
B   | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
C   | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
D   | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
```

Comment: `df = df.set_index('tag').T`

Comment: The question you asked is same as this https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/13475510

Comment: @saqx1: `df_new = df.T`
`df_new.columns = df_new.iloc[0]`