# Assign line colors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot some data in pandas and the inbuilt plot function conveniently plots one line per column. What I want to do is to manually assign each line a color based on a classification I make.

The following works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 2, 3, 4], '2': [1, 2, 1, 2]})
s = pd.Series(['c','y'], index=['1','2'])
df.plot(color = s)
```

But when my indices are integers it no longer works and throws as KeyError:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 1, 2]})
s = pd.Series(['c','y'], index=[1,2])
df.plot(color = s)
```

The way I understand it is that when an integer index is used it somehow has to start from 0. That is my guess since the following works as well:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [1, 2, 1, 2]})
s = pd.Series(['c','y'], index=[1,0])
df.plot(color = s)
```

My question is:

- What is happening here?
- Assuming I have an integer index that does not start from 0 or is not formed of successive numbers, how can I make this work without having to convert the index to string or reindex starting from 0?

EDIT:

I realised that even in the first case, the code doesn't do what I expected it to do.
It seems like pandas matches the index of DataFrame and Series only if both are integer indices starting from 0. If that isn't the case, a KeyError is thrown or if the index is a str the order of the elements is used.

Is this correct? And is there a way to match the Series and DataFrame indices? Or do I have to make sure I pass a list of colours in the right order?

Comment: You don't want the indices to match.  You are matching the Series' Index to the DataFrame's columns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**What is happening here?**

The keyword argument color is inherited from [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). The details in the documentation don't make it clear that you can put in a list of colors when plotting.  Given that color is a keyword argument from matplotlib, I'd recommend not using a Pandas Series to hold the color values.

**How can I make this work?**

Use a list instead of a Series.  If you were using a Series with an index meant to match the columns of your DataFrame to specific colors, you will need to sort the Series first. If the columns are not in order, you will need to [sort the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/python-pandas-re-ordering-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-name) as well.

```
# Option 1
s = s.sort_index()
df.plot(color = s.values) # as per Fiabetto's answer

# Option 2
df.plot(color = ['c', 'y']) # other method
```

Comment: I ended up sorting both the Series and the DataFrame and then turned the Series into a list as suggested. This works without a problem, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way, but I can see how there can't be if the color keyword corresponds to matplotlibs (which obviously knows nothing about Series).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Pandas is just a wrapper to matplotlib.  matplotlib allows the user to to almost anything, but it can get really messy.

Answer (score 12):

To set color for each line you can use the parameter `style`. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4], 'B': [1, 3, 9]})
df.plot(style={'A': 'r', 'B': 'g'})
```

[image]

Using the [shortcut string notation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_markers.asp) in the form *marker|line|color* you can also set marker and line types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4], 'B': [1, 3, 9]})
df.plot(style={'A': '*:r', 'B': '+--g'})
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely the most useful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
df.plot(color = s.values)
```

this will assign the colors no matter the scale of the index.

EDIT:

I tried with three columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1, 2, 3, 4], '2': [1, 2, 1, 2], '3': [4, 3, 2, 1]})
s = pd.Series(['c','y','r'], index=[1,3,2])
df.plot(color = s.sort_index().values)
```

and sorting the Series it works.

Comment: This does indeed work, but I have realised that the actual problem seems to be the order. I will edit the question to include that!

Comment: Sorting the Series only helps if the DataFrame's columns are in order.