# Pandas DataFrame Bar Plot - Plot Bars Different Colors From Specific Colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

How do you plot the bars of a bar plot different colors **only** using the pandas dataframe `plot` method?

If I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 3372, 1: 68855, 2: 17948, 3: 708, 4: 9117}}).reset_index()

   index  count
0      0   3372
1      1  68855
2      2  17948
3      3    708
4      4   9117
```

What `df.plot()` arguments do I need to set so each bar in the plot:

1. Uses the 'Paired' colormap
2. Plots each bar a different color

What I am attempting:

```
df.plot(x='index', y='count', kind='bar', label='index', colormap='Paired', use_index=False)
```

The result:

[image: not different colors]

What I already know (yes, this works, but again, my **purpose** is to figure out how to do this with `df.plot` ONLY. Surely it must be possible?):

```
def f(df):
  groups = df.groupby('index')

  for name,group in groups:
    plt.bar(name, group['count'], label=name, align='center')

  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

[image: end result but used for loop]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no argument you can pass to `df.plot` that colorizes the bars differently for a single column.
Since bars for different columns are colorized differently, an option is to transpose the dataframe before plotting,

```
ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', label='index', colormap='Paired')
```

This would now draw the data as part of a subgroup. Therefore some tweaking needs to be applied to set the limits and xlabels correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 3372, 1: 68855, 2: 17948, 3: 708, 4: 9117}}).reset_index()

ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', label='index', colormap='Paired')
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 1.5)
ax.set_xticks([0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2])
ax.set_xticklabels(range(len(df)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

While I guess this solution matches the criteria from the question, there is actually nothing wrong with using `plt.bar`. A single call to `plt.bar` is sufficient

```
plt.bar(range(len(df)), df["count"], color=plt.cm.Paired(np.arange(len(df))))
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 3372, 1: 68855, 2: 17948, 3: 708, 4: 9117}}).reset_index()

plt.bar(range(len(df)), df["count"], color=plt.cm.Paired(np.arange(len(df))))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to color the bar function of its height and add a vertical color bar on the right hand side?

Comment: @AjanO That would be shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204505/python-barplot-with-colorbar/51205723#51205723)

Answer (score 11):

You can colorize each column as you like with the parameter `color`.

For example (for example, with 3 variables):

```
df.plot.bar(color=['C0', 'C1', 'C2'])
```

Note: The strings `'C0', 'C1', ...'` mentioned above are built-in shortcut color handles in matplotlib. They mean the first, second, third default colors in the active color scheme, and so on. In fact, they are just an example, you can use any custom color using the RGB code or any other color convention just as easily.

You can even highlight a specific column, for example, the middle one here:

```
df.plot.bar(color=['C0', 'C1', 'C0'])
```

To reproduce it in the example code given, one can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 3372, 1: 68855, 2: 17948, 3: 708, 4: 9117}}).reset_index()

ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', label='index', color=['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 1.5)
ax.set_xticks([0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2])
ax.set_xticklabels(range(len(df)))
plt.show()
```

Example with different colors:

[image: Example with different colors]

Example with arbitrary repetition of colors:

[image: Example with arbitrary repetition of colors]

Link for reference: [Assign line colors in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525718/assign-line-colors-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

In addition/extension to @Jairo Alves work you can also indicate the specific hex code

```
df.plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20, 8),color=['#5cb85c','#5bc0de','#d9534f'])
```

[image]