# Cannot create bar plot with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a bar plot using `pandas`. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

indexes = ['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q7': [10, 11, 1, 0, 0]}, index=indexes)
df.plot.bar(indexes, df['Q7'].values)
```

By my reckoning this should work but I get a weird `KeyError: 'Strongly agree'` thrown at me. I can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: `df.plot(kind='bar')` or `df.plot.bar()`

Comment: Isn't `plot.bar` just an alias for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By invoking `plot` as a Pandas method, you're referring to the data structures of `df` to make your plot.

The way you have it set up, with `index=indexes`, your bar plot's `x` values are stored in `df.index`.  That's why Wen's suggestion in the comments to just use `df.plot.bar()` will work, as Pandas automatically looks to use `df.index` as the x-axis in this case.

Alternately, you can specify column names for `x` and `y`.  In this case, you can move `indexes` into a column with `reset_index()` and then call the new `index` column explicitly:

```
df.reset_index().plot.bar(x="index", y="Q7")
```

Either approach will yield the correct plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Ok thanks. And if I want to colour each bar differently?

Comment: Pandas isn't designed to support multiple colors for a single column.  (And in general it's often unnecessary, and even confusing, to encode color as a redundant dimension for a categorical axis.)  Still, there's a workaround here, if you really need it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495136/2799941.