# Highlight particular bars in bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df2` is subset of `df1`. I want to draw horizontal bar plot of `df1` having identified `df2` rows (different bar color or something). Thank you.

```
%matplotlib inline 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

d1 = {
    'index' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'col1'  : [5, 8, 6, 4, 2]
}

d2 = {
    'index' : [3, 5], 
    'col1'  : [6, 2]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).set_index(["index"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).set_index(["index"])

df1.plot(kind="barh", grid=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, pandas' `barh` function doesn't let us choose different colors for each bar. [But since that seems to be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495136/1356000), I would elect to *not* use pandas plotting function, but instead directly use matplotlib's function.

In this context, there are plenty of ways to achieve the desired result. Here is one option:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ['C2' if i in df2.index else 'C1' for i in df1.index]
ax.barh(y=df1.index,width=df1.col1,color=c)
ax.grid(False)
```

[image]

@GlobalTraveler 's answer made me think of another solution

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)].append(df2, sort=False).sort_index()
df3.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, grid=False)
```

The first line creates a new dataframe that has the following content:

```
    col1    col2
index       
1   5.0     NaN
2   8.0     NaN
3   NaN     6.0
4   4.0     NaN
5   NaN     2.0
```

plotting this dataframe produces the desired ouput.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to concatenate the dataframes and append nans for missing values

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = {
    'index' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'col1'  : [5, 8, 6, 4, 2]
}

d2 = {
    'index' : [3, 5], 
    'col1'  : [6, 2]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).set_index(["index"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2).set_index(["index"])

plotThis = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)

plotThis.plot(kind = 'barh')
```