# How give different colors for different group of barplots in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot group of bar charts. I was able to give different colors within each group but how to give different colors to different groups?

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



df = pd.DataFrame({0: [10,20,80],
                  1: [20,40,60]},index=['a','b','c'])

df

# another test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [10,20,80,10],
                  1: [20,40,60,70],
                  2: [20,40,60,70],
                  },
                  index=['a','b','c','d'])

pal = 'magma'
color=sns.color_palette(pal,len(df)) # list of rgb

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot.bar(ax=ax,color=color)
```

## Output

[image]

## Required

Here the variable `color` has three values, I want to use these three colors for three groups. For example group `a` now has two colors, I want it to have only one color.

## Similar links

- [python assign different colors to bars in barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885703/python-assign-different-colors-to-bars-in-barplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use axis.patches:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({0: [10,20,80,10],
                  1: [20,40,60,70],
                  2: [20,40,60,70],
                  },
                  index=['a','b','c','d'])

pal = 'magma'
color = sns.color_palette(pal,len(df)) # list of rgb
color = color * df.shape[1]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot.bar(ax=ax)
ax.get_legend().remove()

for p,c in zip(ax.patches,color):
    p.set_color(c)
```

Gives:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround using `plt.bar()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



df = pd.DataFrame({0: [10,20,80],
                  1: [20,40,60],
                  'g':['a','b','c']})

pal = 'magma'
color=sns.color_palette(pal,len(df)) # list of rgb

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


width=.25

gb = df.groupby('g')
positions = range(len(gb))

for c, x, (_, group) in zip(color, positions, gb):

    ax.bar(x-width/2, group[0], width, color=c, edgecolor='k')
    ax.bar(x+width/2, group[1], width, color=c, edgecolor='k')

ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['g'])
```

[image]