# Change the color of lines with categorical column values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot, color-coding

I have the following code:

```
df1['salary'].groupby(df1['job']).mean().plot(kind='line')
```

This gives one line as output. I want to have two lines in the output based on another column which is gender.

I tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
df1['salary'].groupby(df1['job']).mean().plot(kind='line', color=df1['gender'])
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: This is a typical case for which seaborn has been invented: `sns.lineplot(data=df1, x='job', y='salary', hue='gender')`.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you so much. I have been searching for 4 hours just for this code! I appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47104862/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32525718/7758804

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  I am wondering when we use y in this code: sns.lineplot(data=df1, x='job', y='salary', hue='gender')  does it consider average salary by default??

Comment: If there are values to be aggregated, that what `estimator` : _name of pandas method or callable or None_ is for (e.g. `estimator='mean'`), which is the default.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you so much. what if I want to count values. df1['job'].value_counts().plot(kind='line') and change color by gender

Comment: Use [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html). Otherwise, use `estimator='size'` or maybe `estimator='count'`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney but I want it to be line. countplot gives bar chart. how should i change it to line chart?

Comment: Something like `pd.crosstab(df1.salary, df1.job).plot()`. It's really a different question.

Comment: Thank you so much :)