# Reorder Dataframe columns contains string and number in ascending order

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried reordering the column using `sort_index`, but it doesn't behave as I had hoped.

After sorting, it reorders as below:

```
>>> list(df)
['blocks_written_1',
 'blocks_written_10',
 'blocks_written_11',
 'blocks_written_12',
 'blocks_written_2',
 'blocks_written_3',
 'blocks_written_4',
 'blocks_written_5',
 'blocks_written_6',
 'blocks_written_7',
 'blocks_written_8',
 'blocks_written_9']
```

But I am looking for something like below:

```
blocks_written_1,
blocks_written_2,
..,
blocks_written_9,
blocks_written_10,
blocks_written_11,
blocks_written_12
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/python-pandas-re-ordering-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-name this should work

Comment: @GauravTaneja The solution to your link above would result in in the OP's top list of ordering which is not the desired result (due to how text integers are sorted).

Comment: forgot to add, in the link I provided, @Jeremy Low provides a answer that take cares of that. Super thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create sample data.
n = ['1', '10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
initial_cols = ['blocks_written_{}'.format(i) for i in n]
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, len(initial_cols)), columns=initial_cols)

# Split column names on underscore and take integer of last item.
cols = [(col, int(col.split('_')[-1])) for col in df]
# Sort column name, integer tuple pairs on integer value.
cols.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# Rearrange dataframe based on new column order.
df = df[[col[0] for col in cols]]

>>> df
   blocks_written_1  blocks_written_2  blocks_written_3  blocks_written_4  \
0          1.764052          1.867558         -0.977278          0.950088   
1          0.761038          1.494079         -0.205158          0.313068   
2          2.269755          1.532779          1.469359          0.154947   
3          1.230291         -1.048553         -1.420018         -1.706270   
4         -1.613898         -0.510805         -1.180632         -0.028182   

   blocks_written_5  blocks_written_6  blocks_written_7  blocks_written_8  \
0         -0.151357         -0.103219          0.410599          0.144044   
1         -0.854096         -2.552990          0.653619          0.864436   
2          0.378163         -0.887786         -1.980796         -0.347912   
3          1.950775         -0.509652         -0.438074         -1.252795   
4          0.428332          0.066517          0.302472         -0.634322   

   blocks_written_9  blocks_written_10  blocks_written_11  blocks_written_12  
0          1.454274           0.400157           0.978738           2.240893  
1         -0.742165           0.121675           0.443863           0.333674  
2          0.156349          -1.454366           0.045759          -0.187184  
3          0.777490           1.202380          -0.387327          -0.302303  
4         -0.362741          -0.212740          -0.895467           0.386902
```