# How to arange columns of test dataframe in same sequence as that of the train dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following train dataframe kind of dataframe,
train_df

```
A   B   C   D
6   8   7   3
7   9   1   8
11  7   2   3
```

and my test dataframe columns arrangement is as following,
test_df

```
C   A   D   B
4   2   3   9
7   4   7   3
5   1   2   4
```

I want my test_df as following

```
A   B   C   D
2   9   4   3
4   3   7   7
1   4   5   2
```

I have 300 such mixed columns in my test_df how to match sequence of test_df with that of train_df?

Comment: Apart from order - do all the column names match? If so - you most likely don't need this and if they don't - not sure how you'd rearrange them to match otherwise.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067072/9511702) to sort columns names.

Comment: Are you just asking how to reorder your `test_df` columns? You can just do `test_df.reindex_axis(train_df.columns, axis=1)` besides does this matter?

Comment: yes, all column names match

Comment: @EdChum I'm guessing it'll make comparing them visually in tabular form easier but apart from that...

Comment: yes, exactly....Got it, Thank you EdChum.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag

Answer (score 0):

```
test_df.reindex_axis(train_df.columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer. Without any further comment answers like this might be deleted by moderators due to low quality.

Comment: I didn't get you...what you mean to say