# How to order pandas datafame column by given a list of column

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a pandas dataframe like this :

```
    T2  T4  T3  T1  Time
1  0.1 0.7 0.6 0.2 18:00
2  0.3 0.4 0.1 0.4 16:00
3  0.2 0.3 0.2 0.9 20:00
4  0.1 0.7 0.5 0.4 19:00
5  0.1 0.4 0.8 0.9 17:00
```

If I have a list :

```
column_order = ["T1","T2","T3","T4","Time"]
```

How do I reorder the pandas dataframe to this by given `column_order`:

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  Time
1  0.2 0.1 0.6 0.7 18:00
2  0.4 0.3 0.1 0.4 16:00
3  0.9 0.2 0.2 0.3 20:00
4  0.4 0.1 0.5 0.7 19:00
5  0.9 0.1 0.8 0.4 17:00
```

I have done some research [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/python-pandas-re-ordering-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-name) but none of them mention how to reorder pandas dataframe column by given column name order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, `df[column_order]` not working ?

Comment: That is not working becasue I have column name `T30`, and the order will be `T1` `T2` `T30` `T4`.

Comment: It is not first answer in dupe, but third - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29922207

Comment: Sorry, not understand - `column_order = ["T1","T2","T30","T4","Time"]` should working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks `jezrael`, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: `df1 = df[['T1','T2','T3','T4','Time']]`

Comment: Answer my self : `df[column_order ]`