# arranging pandas dataframe columns by name (alphanumerically)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with columns named alphanumerically as
'A#1 , A#0.25, A#10, A#2, B#1, B#0.25, B#10, B#2'

I want to arrange them alphanumerically like 'A#0.25, A#1, A#10, A#2, B#0.25, B#1, B#2, B#10'- so first on alphabetical part before # and then on numeric part after #.

Is there a way to do this directly ?

Comment: Check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name

Answer (score 1):

Using `natsort`

```
import natsort
df=df.reindex(columns=natsort.natsorted(df.columns))
df
Out[115]: 
   A#0.25  A#1  A#2  A#10  B#0.25  B#1  B#2  B#10
0       0    0    0     0       0    0    0     0
```

---

Data input

```
df
Out[112]: 
   A#1  A#0.25  A#10  A#2  B#1  B#0.25  B#10  B#2
0    0       0     0    0    0       0     0    0
```

Comment: thanks @Wen-Ben. I wonder if there is a way to do this without using another library and staying within numpy/pandas