# Can't Re-Order Columns Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe not sequences. if I use `len(df.columns)`, my data has 3586 columns. How to re-order the data sequences?

```
ID  V1  V10 V100 V1000 V1001 V1002 ...  V990 V991 V992 V993 V994
A   1   9.0 2.9  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B   1   1.2 0.1  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C   2   8.6 8.0  2.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
D   3   0.0 2.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
E   4   7.8 6.6  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I used this `df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)` (based on this question [Re-ordering columns in pandas dataframe based on column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name)) but still not working.

thank you

Comment: use `data.reindex_axis(sorted(data.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])), axis=1)`

Comment: its in the answer of the like you posted, and `sorted(df.columns)` will sort list based on string, not based on `int`, because you have `V`

Comment: @Nihal - I got an error `could not convert string to float: 'ac'`

Comment: what is `ac`?? in your dataframe? can you please post the output of `print(list(df.columns))`

Comment: @Nihal -  I used `print(list(df.columns))` and the result is ID and all 'V' with number but not sequence. I don't know where the `ac` come from

Comment: @Arief - Edited answer, it should working with `ac` columns too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get all columns without pattern `V` + `number` by filtering with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then sorting all another values by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html), add together and pass to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - get first all non numeric non matched columns in first positions and then sorted `V` + `number` columns:

```
L1 = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('^V\d+$')].tolist()

L2 = sorted(df.columns.difference(L1), key=lambda x: float(x[1:]))

df = df.reindex(L1 + L2, axis=1)
print (df)
   ID   V1  V10  V100  V990  V991  V992  V993  V994  V1000  V1001  V1002
A   1  9.0  2.9   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
B   1  1.2  0.1   3.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
C   2  8.6  8.0   2.0   2.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
D   3  0.0  2.0   0.0   3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
E   4  7.8  6.6   3.0   4.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```