# Re-order row data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, row

Based on this question [Can't Re-Order Columns Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570389/cant-re-order-columns-data), how to do it for the `dataframe` row? because I have a problem, not in the column order but the row order.

my data looks like this:

```
    B1  B2
B1  1   1
B10 1   1
B11 1   1
B12 1   1
B2  1   1
B20 1   1
B21 1   1
B22 1   1
B3  1   1
B30 1   1
B31 1   1
```

my expected result:

```
    B1  B2
 B1 1   1
 B2 1   1
 B3 1   1
B10 1   1
B11 1   1
B12 1   1
B20 1   1
B21 1   1
B22 1   1
B30 1   1
B31 1   1
```

Comment: Can you create some small DataFrame with expcted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
import natsort as ns
df.reindex(ns.natsorted(df.index))
```

---

```
     B1  B2
B1    1   1
B2    1   1
B3    1   1
B10   1   1
B11   1   1
B12   1   1
B20   1   1
B21   1   1
B22   1   1
B30   1   1
B31   1   1
```

Or:

```
i=df.index.to_series().str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float).sort_values().index
df.reindex(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter `key` in sorted function and pass output to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])))
print (df)
     B1  B2
B1    1   1
B2    1   1
B3    1   1
B10   1   1
B11   1   1
B12   1   1
B20   1   1
B21   1   1
B22   1   1
B30   1   1
B31   1   1
```

Alternative is [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) numeric, convert to floats and get positions of sorted values by [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html), last change order by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float).argsort()]
print (df)
     B1  B2
B1    1   1
B2    1   1
B3    1   1
B10   1   1
B11   1   1
B12   1   1
B20   1   1
B21   1   1
B22   1   1
B30   1   1
B31   1   1
```