# i have a Dataframe with a data column ranging from 2005-01-01 to 2014-12-31. How do i sort the columns?

Tags: python, data-science

input:

```
data["Date"] = ["2005-01-01", "2005-01-02" , ""2005-01-03" ,..., "2014-12-30","2014-12-31"]
```

how can i sort the column such that the column gives 1st date of every year, 2nd date of every and so on:

i.e.

output:

```
data["Date"] = ["2005-01-01","2006-01-01","2007-01-01", ... "2013-12-31","2014-12-31"]
```

**NOTE: assuming the date column has no leap days**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name
try what suggested here, but before create a sorted list of your years

Comment: Do you want the entire dataframe to be sorted on `Date` or just the `Date` column?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma  i want entire dataframe to be sorted by "Date" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
data['D'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
data['Day'] = data['D'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
data['Month'] = data['D'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
data['Year'] = data['D'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
data.drop(columns='D', inplace=True)
```

Then, having 4 columns dataframe, we sort as following:

```
data.sort_values(by=['Day','Month','Year'], inplace=True)
```

Finally, you can drop new columns if you won't need them:

```
data.drop(columns = ['Day','Month','Year'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for such quick response. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lambda expressions.

```
from datetime import datetime

data = {"Date": ["2005-01-02", "2005-01-01", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31"]}
data["Date"].sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in data["Date"]]
>>> dates.sort()
>>> sorteddates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in dates]
>>> sorteddates
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-11-16', '2010-11-
22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011
-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for the response.

Comment: It's our responsibility buddy to keep the Community Informative and Helpful

Comment: and to add on your question. It will handle the Leap Years also.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont't you try and create a new column in which you change the format of the date? 
Like this :

```
def change_format(row):
    date_parts = row.split('-')
    new_date = date_parts(2)+"-"+date_parts(1)+"-"+date_parts(0)
    return new_date

data["Date_new_format"] = data["Date"].apply(lambda row => change_format(row))
```

Now you can sort your dataframe according to the column Date_new_format and you will get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data["temp"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]).dt.strftime("%d-%Y-%m")
data = data.sort_values(by="temp").drop(columns=["temp"])
```