# Arrange columns position in pandas based on specified string arrangement

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with similar column names between 'A' and 'B' as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A_Text1':1, 'A_Text2':2, 'A_Text3':3, 'B_Text1':4, 'B_Text2':5, 'B_Text3':6, 'A_Text4':7,  'B_Text4':8})
```

When i use solution from here, [Re-ordering columns in pandas dataframe based on column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name) I will get as such because it arrange alphabetically:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A_Text1':1, 'A_Text2':2, 'A_Text3':3, 'A_Text4':7, 'B_Text1':4, 'B_Text2':5, 'B_Text3':6, 'B_Text4':8})
```

What I truly need is to be able to arrange the column names by how I want to as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A_Text3':3, 'A_Text4':7, 'A_Text1':1, 'A_Text2':2, 'B_Text3':6, 'B_Text4':8, 'B_Text1':4, 'B_Text2':5})
```

Where the arrangement of column names with "_Text" is always like I specified above (_Text3, _Text4, _Text1, _Text2) because i have hundreds of columns with similar "_Text" name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use mapping by helper `dictionary` for custom order with another dictionary for replace in `rename`, last is used [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for changed order by new columns names:

```
order = {'Text3':'1', 'Text4':'2', 'Text1':'3', 'Text2':'4'}

d = df.columns.to_series().replace(order, regex=True).to_dict()

print (df.rename(columns=d).columns)
Index(['A_3', 'A_4', 'A_1', 'B_3', 'B_4', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
df = df.iloc[:, df.rename(columns=d).columns.argsort()]
print (df)

   A_Text3  A_Text4  A_Text1  A_Text2  B_Text3  B_Text4  B_Text1  B_Text2
0        3        7        1        2        6        8        4        5
```

You can also create dictionary dynamic, also added zeros for correct sorting if 10+ columns in list:

```
order = ['Text3', 'Text4', 'Text1', 'Text2']

order_d = {v: f'{k:03}' for k, v in enumerate(order, 1)}
print (order_d)
{'Text3': '001', 'Text4': '002', 'Text1': '003', 'Text2': '004'}

d = df.columns.to_series().replace(order_d, regex=True)
print (df.rename(columns=d).columns)
Index(['A_003', 'A_004', 'A_001',
       'B_003', 'B_004', 'B_001', 'A_002', 'B_002'], dtype='object')

df = df.iloc[:, df.rename(columns=d).columns.argsort()]
print (df)
   A_Text3  A_Text4  A_Text1  A_Text2  B_Text3  B_Text4  B_Text1  B_Text2
0        3        7        1        2        6        8        4        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try `pd.Categorical` the first idea is to create a dataframe of your columns and extract the alpha and numeric representation

then we apply a categorical sort.

```
s = df.columns.to_frame('')

s = s.join(s[0].str.extract("(\w)_\D+(\d)").rename(columns={0: "alpha", 1: "numeric"}))

print(s)

         0 alpha numeric
0  A_Text1     A       1
1  A_Text2     A       2
2  A_Text3     A       3
3  B_Text1     B       1
4  B_Text2     B       2
5  B_Text3     B       3
6  A_Text4     A       4
7  B_Text4     B       4

#define your custom order.
order = [3,4,1,2]
s['numeric'] = pd.Categorical(s['numeric'].astype(int),order,ordered=True)
s_ordered = s.sort_values(['alpha','numeric'])


         0 alpha numeric
2  A_Text3     A       3
6  A_Text4     A       4
0  A_Text1     A       1
1  A_Text2     A       2
5  B_Text3     B       3
7  B_Text4     B       4
3  B_Text1     B       1
4  B_Text2     B       2
```

---

then assign back to your columns.

```
df.columns = s_ordered[0].tolist()

  A_Text3  A_Text4  A_Text1  A_Text2  B_Text3  B_Text4  B_Text1  B_Text2
0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
```