# Split single Dataframe Column into multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I have data along the lines below (although many more rows than the example of course).  The data can appear in diferent order.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'SmVariant': ['1xFBBC', float('nan'), '2xFBBA', '5xABIA', \
                                '2xFBBC, 1xFBBA', '1xFBBA', '4xABIA', \
                                '1xFBBA, 1xFBBC', float('nan'), '1xFBBA', \
                                '3xFBBA, 1xFBBC']})
```

I want to split into numerical columns like this: (ultimately to get totals)

```
FBBA  FBBC  ABIA
1           
          
2            
              5
1       2
1
              4
1       1

1
3       1
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You can do it in a single line using `regex` + `pandas` *method-chaining* as follows. I have broken it into multiple lines for better readability. For more details please see **Section C** below.   ⭐

> Note: Sections A and B use the data from section D, which the OP had shared earlier. Later the data in the question was changed and **Section C** gives the solution to this use-case.

**Regex Examples:**

In the interest of explaining the how `regex-pattern` works, please take a look at the following three examples:

- **[*example-1*](https://regex101.com/r/UXhHRl/2)**: I have used this regex pattern in **Section-A**. This will help work given we have the data as given in **Section-D**.
- **[*example-2*](https://regex101.com/r/Ek90Mu/1)**: This is an improved version of the regex in example-1. I have used this regex pattern in **Section-B *and* C**.
- **[*example-3*](https://regex101.com/r/UDQQnN/1)**: Finally, this example illustrates how the pattern used in example-2 could skip unwanted text and only pick intended text-parrens.

```py
# without alphabetically ordering the columns
(df[COLUMN_NAME]                                                   ## access the "data"-column
    .fillna('0xUNKN')                                              ## replace nan values with 0xUNKN 
    .str.findall(pat)                                              ## use regex to extract patterns
    .apply(lambda x: dict((k, v) for v, k in x if (int(v)!=0)))    ## row-wise create dict to construct final {column: count} structure
    .apply(pd.Series)                                              ## use dict to create columns
    .fillna(0)                                                     ## replace NaN values with 0
)
```

### A. Each operation with explanation

Here I explain what each operation does and finally reorder the columns alphabetically.

> **Regex Explanation: [*example-1*](https://regex101.com/r/UXhHRl/2)**
>
> Find a detailed explanation of how the regex `(\d+)x(\w+)\s*,\s*(\d+)x(\w+)` works to extract various intended parts from the input text here: [example-1](https://regex101.com/r/UXhHRl/2).
>
> [image]

```py
# NOTE: I am using the dataframe that I created in 
# the Dummy Data section "below"

df2 = (df.data                                      # access the "data"-column
    .str.findall('(\d+)x(\w+)\s*,\s*(\d+)x(\w+)')   # use regex to extract patterns
    .explode()                                      # explode each rows' list into columns
    .apply(lambda x: {x[1]: x[0], x[3]: x[2]})      # row-wise create dict to construct final {column: count} structure
    .apply(pd.Series)                               # expand each cell into columns
    .fillna(0)                                      # replace NaN values with 0
)
df2 = df2.reindex(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1)      # alphabetically reorder columns
print(df2)
```

**Output**:

```sh
  AAAA BBBB CCCC
0    1    1    0
1    1    2    0
2    1    0    1
```

### B. A more generic solution

If you have more than two types per line (say, `AAAA`, `BBBB`, `CCCC`), the following solution will work in that case as well.

> **Regex Explanation: [*example-2*](https://regex101.com/r/Ek90Mu/1)**
>
> Find a detailed explanation of how the regex `(?:\s*(\d+)x(\w+)\s*)+` works to extract various intended parts from the input text here: [example-2](https://regex101.com/r/Ek90Mu/1).
>
> [image]

#### Code

```py
import pandas as pd

## Dummy Data
data = [
    '1xAAAA,2xBBBB,3xDDDD', 
    '1xBBBB,1xAAAA,6xEEEE', 
    '1xAAAA,1xCCCC,3xDDDD', 
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data'])
print('\n Input:')
print(df)
## Output:
#                    data
# 0  1xAAAA,2xBBBB,3xDDDD
# 1  1xBBBB,1xAAAA,6xEEEE
# 2  1xAAAA,1xCCCC,3xDDDD

## Process DataFrame
# define regex pattern    
pat = '(?:\s*(\d+)x(\w+)\s*)+' # regex search pattern
# create dataframe in the expected format
df2 = (df.data                                      ## access the "data"-column
    .str.findall(pat)                               ## use regex to extract patterns
    .apply(lambda x: dict((k, v) for v, k in x))    ## row-wise create dict to construct final {column: count} structure
    .apply(pd.Series)                               ## use dict to create columns
    .fillna(0)                                      ## replace NaN values with 0
)
df2 = df2.reindex(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1)      ## alphabetically reorder columns
print('\n Output:')
print(df2)

## Output:
#   AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
# 0    1    2    0    3    0
# 1    1    1    0    0    6
# 2    1    0    1    3    0
```

### C. Specific Example for Data Shared by the OP  ⭐

Here is an example on the specific sample-data shared by the OP. This specific use-case shows the presence of *nan* values in the dataframe. As a strategy to use the previously suggested solution with minimal modification, you could just `replace` those **nan** values with a string `0xUNKN` and then filter the results that do not start with a `0`.

```py
import pandas as pd

COLUMN_NAME = 'SmVariant'

## Dummy Data
data = [
    '1xFBBC', float('nan'), 
    '2xFBBA', '5xABIA', 
    '2xFBBC, 1xFBBA', 
    '1xFBBA', '4xABIA', 
    '1xFBBA, 1xFBBC', 
    float('nan'), '1xFBBA', 
    '3xFBBA, 1xFBBC', 
]
df = pd.DataFrame({COLUMN_NAME: data})
print('\n Input:')
print(df)
## Output:
#          SmVariant
# 0           1xFBBC
# 1              NaN
# 2           2xFBBA
# 3           5xABIA
# 4   2xFBBC, 1xFBBA
# 5           1xFBBA
# 6           4xABIA
# 7   1xFBBA, 1xFBBC
# 8              NaN
# 9           1xFBBA
# 10  3xFBBA, 1xFBBC

## Process DataFrame
# define regex pattern    
pat = '(?:\s*(\d+)x(\w+)\s*)+' # regex search pattern
# create dataframe in the expected format
df2 = (df[COLUMN_NAME]                                             ## access the "data"-column
    .fillna('0xUNKN')                                              ## replace nan values with 0xUNKN 
    .str.findall(pat)                                              ## use regex to extract patterns
    .apply(lambda x: dict((k, v) for v, k in x if (int(v)!=0)))    ## row-wise create dict to construct final {column: count} structure
    .apply(pd.Series)                                              ## use dict to create columns
    .fillna(0)                                                     ## replace NaN values with 0
)
df2 = df2.reindex(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1)                     ## alphabetically reorder columns
print('\n Output:')
print(df2)

## Output:
#    ABIA FBBA FBBC
# 0     0    0    1
# 1     0    0    0
# 2     0    2    0
# 3     5    0    0
# 4     0    1    2
# 5     0    1    0
# 6     4    0    0
# 7     0    1    1
# 8     0    0    0
# 9     0    1    0
# 10    0    3    1
```

### D. Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    '1xAAAA,2xBBBB', 
    '1xBBBB,1xAAAA', 
    '1xAAAA,1xCCCC', 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data'])
print(df)
## Output:
#             data
# 0  1xBBBB,1xAAAA
# 1  1xAAAA,2xBBBB
# 2  1xAAAA,1xCCCC
```

### References

1. [Re-ordering columns in pandas dataframe based on column name [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name)
2. [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)
3. [Expand Cells Containing Lists Into Their Own Variables In Pandas](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists/)

Comment: @Wayne_AB Let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into the solution when I have some time.  Could you please explain the regex a bit?

Comment: @Wayne_AB I have added two examples in the solution: the first one will explain the first pattern step by step and the second one (which is a more concise and generic version of the first one), will explain you each steps in it. [example-1](https://regex101.com/r/UXhHRl/1) and [example-2](https://regex101.com/r/Ek90Mu/1/).

Comment: Here is a better sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'SmVariant': ['1xFBBC', float('nan'), '2xFBBA', '5xABIA', \
                                '2xFBBC, 1xFBBA', '1xFBBA', '4xABIA', \
                                '1xFBBA, 1xFBBC', float('nan'), '1xFBBA', \
                                '3xFBBA, 1xFBBC']})

Comment: See this: [example-3](https://regex101.com/r/UDQQnN/1).

Comment: @Wayne_AB: See **section C** in my solution.

Comment: CypherX, if you have added ex1-3, I am very grateful.  I think it is the right solution to handle variable length data.  But I am getting an error I believe is related to NaN data.

Comment: Thank you.  I am 110% blown away by the response.  I am an electronic engineer who has not done any coding for many years.  I started with Pascal many moons ago, and more recently have used VisualBasic which is too weak and outdated for my purposes.  This is a fantastic resource and I am extremely grateful. Thanks CypherX.

Comment: @Wayne_AB I am glad the answer helped you. Please consider **`voting-up`** and **`accepting`** the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a pandas DataFrame.  I also assume that you know the different types of element upfront and can put them into a dictionary like so (to map the elements into the final columns:

```
cols={'AAAA':0, 'BBBB': 1, 'CCCC': 2}
```

Next write a function that converts a specific element into the multiple columns:

```
def expand_element(el):
  res = [0]*len(cols)
  for item in el.split(','):
    q, name = item.split('x')
    res[cols[name]]=int(q)
  return res
```

Finally, use that function and apply it to each element in your dataframe as follows:

```
df.apply(lambda x: expand_element(x[0]), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Here is my interactive session showing input and outputs:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"c1": ["1xAAAA,2xBBBB", "1xAAAA,2xBBBB"]})
>>> df.apply(lambda x: expand_element(x[0]), axis=1, result_type='expand')
   0  1  2
0  1  2  0
1  1  2  0
```

Comment: That looks interesting.  I do want to maintain the "AAAA", "BBBB" etc as headings.