# Polars: Pivoting by Int64 column not keeping numeric order

Tags: python-polars

I have a column called `VERSION_INDEX` which is Int64 and is a proxy for keeping a list of semantic software versions ordered such that 0.2.0 comes after 0.13.0.  When I pivot, the column names created from the pivot are sorted alphanumerically.

```
pivot_df = merged_df.pivot(index=test_events_key_columns, columns='VERSION_INDEX', values='Status')
print(pivot_df)
```

[image]

Is it possible to keep the column order numeric during the pivot such that 9 comes before 87?

thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting columns in pandas dataframe based on column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/sorting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name)

Comment: @ASHMIL No that is a `pandas` solution, not a `polars` solution

Comment: I know how to post-process the `polars` column order, just wondering if a sort order can be introduced during the `pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polars, column names are always stored as strings, and hence you have the alphanumeric sorting rather than numeric. There is no way around the strings, so I think the best you can do is to compute the column order you want, and select the columns:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"version": [9, 85, 87], "testsuite": ["scan1", "scan2", "scan3"], "status": ["ok"] * 3})
wide = df.pivot(index="testsuite", columns='version', values='status')
cols = df["version"].cast(pl.Utf8).to_list()
wide[["testsuite"] + cols]
```

```
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ testsuite ┆ 9    ┆ 85   ┆ 87   │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str       ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ scan1     ┆ ok   ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ scan2     ┆ null ┆ ok   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ scan3     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ ok   │
└───────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```