# Pandas pivot_table. How to change sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot-table

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
            alpha1    week_day    calendar_week
0             2.49     Freitag  2022-04-(01/07)
1             1.32     Samstag  2022-04-(01/07)
2             2.70     Sonntag  2022-04-(01/07)
3             3.81      Montag  2022-04-(01/07)
4             3.58    Dienstag  2022-04-(01/07)
5             3.48    Mittwoch  2022-04-(01/07)
6             1.79  Donnerstag  2022-04-(01/07)
7             2.12     Freitag  2022-04-(08/14)
8             2.41     Samstag  2022-04-(08/14)
9             1.78     Sonntag  2022-04-(08/14)
10            3.19      Montag  2022-04-(08/14)
11            3.33    Dienstag  2022-04-(08/14)
12            2.88    Mittwoch  2022-04-(08/14)
13            2.98  Donnerstag  2022-04-(08/14)
14            3.01     Freitag  2022-04-(15/21)
15            3.04     Samstag  2022-04-(15/21)
16            2.72     Sonntag  2022-04-(15/21)
17            4.11      Montag  2022-04-(15/21)
18            3.90    Dienstag  2022-04-(15/21)
19            3.16    Mittwoch  2022-04-(15/21)
```

and so on, with ascending calendar weeks.
I performed a pivot table to generate a heatmap. 
`df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['alpha1'], index=['week_day'], columns=['calendar_week'])`
What I get is:

```
                  alpha1                                        \
calendar_week 2022-(04-29/05-05) 2022-(05-27/06-02) 2022-(07-29/08-04)   
week_day                                                                 
Dienstag                    3.32               2.09               4.04   
Donnerstag                  3.27               2.21               4.65   
Freitag                     2.83               3.08               4.19   
Mittwoch                    3.22               3.14               4.97   
Montag                      2.83               2.86               4.28   
Samstag                     2.62               3.62               3.88   
Sonntag                     2.81               3.25               3.77   

                                                                  \
calendar_week 2022-(08-26/09-01) 2022-04-(01/07) 2022-04-(08/14)   
week_day                                                           
Dienstag                    2.92            3.58            3.33   
Donnerstag                  3.58            1.79            2.98   
Freitag                     3.96            2.49            2.12   
Mittwoch                    3.09            3.48            2.88   
Montag                      3.85            3.81            3.19   
Samstag                     3.10            1.32            2.41   
Sonntag                     3.39            2.70            1.78
```

As you see the sorting of the pivot table is messed up. I need the same sorting for the columns (calendar weeks) as in the original dataframe.
I have been looking all over but couldn't find how to achieve this.
Would be also very nice, if the sorting of the rows remains the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE** 
I didn't paste all the data. It would have been too long
The `calendar_week` column consist of following elements

```
'2022-04-(01/07)', 
'2022-04-(08/14)',
'2022-04-(15/21)', 
'2022-04-(22/28)', 
'2022-(04-29/05-05)', 
'2022-05-(06/12)',
'2022-05-(13/19)',
'2022-05-(20/26)',
'2022-(05-27/06-02)', 
'2022-06-(03/09)'
'2022-06-(10/16)'
'2022-06-(17/23)'
'2022-06-(24/30)'
'2022-07-(01/07)'
'2022-07-(08/14)'
'2022-07-(15/21)'
'2022-07-(22/28)'
'2022-(07-29/08-04)'
'2022-08-(05/11)'
etc....
```

Each occurs 7 times in `df`. It represents a calendar week. 
The sorting is the natural time sorting.
After pivoting the dataframe, the sorting of the column get messed up. And I guess it's due to the 2 different types: `2022-(07-29/08-04)` and `2022-07-(15/21)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11067027/10315163 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
df_pivot.sort_values(by = ['calendar_week'], axis = 1, ascending = True)
```

I got the following output. Is this what you wanted?

| calendar_week | 2022-04-(01/07) | 2022-04-(08/14) | 2022-04-(15/21) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| week_day |  |  |  |
| Dienstag | 3.58 | 3.33 | 3.90 |
| Donnerstag | 1.79 | 2.98 | NaN |
| Freitag | 2.49 | 2.12 | 3.01 |
| Mittwoch | 3.48 | 2.88 | 3.16 |
| Montag | 3.81 | 3.19 | 4.11 |

be sure to remove the NaN values using the fillna() function.

I hope that answers it. :)

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. Thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for your week days and sort the dates after pivoting with [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
# define the desired order of the days
days = ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag',
        'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag']

df_pivot = (df
            .assign(week_day=pd.Categorical(df['week_day'], categories=days,
                                            ordered=True))
            .pivot_table(values='alpha1', index='week_day',
                         columns='calendar_week')
            .sort_index(axis=1)
           )
```

output:

```
calendar_week  2022-04-(01/07)  2022-04-(08/14)  2022-04-(15/21)
week_day                                                        
Montag                    3.81             3.19             4.11
Dienstag                  3.58             3.33             3.90
Mittwoch                  3.48             2.88             3.16
Donnerstag                1.79             2.98              NaN
Freitag                   2.49             2.12             3.01
Samstag                   1.32             2.41             3.04
Sonntag                   2.70             1.78             2.72
```

Comment: This is working well for the rows but it's not sorting the columns.

Comment: What I need most is sorting the columns.

Comment: How do you want to sort the columns? Seems to work for me

Comment: No, it's not working. I think it's due to the terms in `calendar_week` that looks like this: `2022-(08-26/09-01)`

Comment: Then your example is not reproducible, can you update and clarify the logic? But even `YYYY-(MM-DD/MM-DD)` should sort correctly as string

Comment: I updated my question. I hope the problem is clear now. And your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Which assumption? Also you still haven't explained the exact sorting logic. How to compare different formats is ambiguous without a clear logic.

Comment: I explained quite well, actually. The natural time sorting should be kept after the pivoting. This is exactly what's not happening.

Comment: OK, then good luck, I hope you find what you want.